# How to find all occurrences of a substring?

Tags: python, string

Python has `string.find()` and `string.rfind()` to get the index of a substring in a string.

I'm wondering whether there is something like `string.find_all()` which can return all found indexes (not only the first from the beginning or the first from the end).

For example:

```
string = "test test test test"

print string.find('test') # 0
print string.rfind('test') # 15

#this is the goal
print string.find_all('test') # [0,5,10,15]
```

---

<sub>For *counting* the occurrences, see [Count number of occurrences of a substring in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899905).</sub>

Comment: what should `'ttt'.find_all('tt')` return?

Comment: it should return '0'. Of course, in perfect world there also has to be `'ttt'.rfind_all('tt')`, which should return '1'

Answer (score 786, accepted):

There is no simple built-in string function that does what you're looking for, but you could use the more powerful [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/):

```
import re
[m.start() for m in re.finditer('test', 'test test test test')]
#[0, 5, 10, 15]
```

If you want to find overlapping matches, [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) will do that:

```
[m.start() for m in re.finditer('(?=tt)', 'ttt')]
#[0, 1]
```

If you want a reverse find-all without overlaps, you can combine positive and negative lookahead into an expression like this:

```
search = 'tt'
[m.start() for m in re.finditer('(?=%s)(?!.{1,%d}%s)' % (search, len(search)-1, search), 'ttt')]
#[1]
```

[`re.finditer`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.finditer) returns a [generator](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), so you could change the `[]` in the above to `()` to get a generator instead of a list which will be more efficient if you're only iterating through the results once.

Comment: hi, concerning this `[m.start() for m in re.finditer('test', 'test test test test')]`, how can we look for `test` or `text`? Does it become much more complicated?

Comment: You want to look into regular expression in general : https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html. The solution to your question will be : [m.start() for m in re.finditer('te[sx]t', 'text test text test')]

Comment: What will be the time complexity of using this method ?

Comment: @PranjalMittal. Upper or lower bound? Best, worst or average case?

Comment: @marcog what if the substring contains parentheses or other special characters?

Comment: This method doesn't work with overlapping strings, e.g. when searching for "ACA" in string "ACACA", it will return only index 0. In case, someone wants a solution, here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3873422/6430403. Use the find method with index += 1.

Comment: I would recommend escaping the search strings as well, like this: `[m.start() for m in re.finditer(re.escape(search_str), input_str)]`

Comment: Applied method to search for substrings in a text file, got: "error: nothing to repeat at position 0"

Comment: I want overlapping matches. If the substring or string contain leading and lagging spaces, i got and error: expected string or bytes-like object. I need the spaces, because I don't want to match "really mean" to "really meaningful"

Comment: This doesn't work with multi-word subwords. For example, `THIS SUB-WORD` in this sentence `Find THIS SUB-WORD in this sentence with THIS SUB-WORD` .

Answer (score 178):

```
>>> help(str.find)
Help on method_descriptor:

find(...)
    S.find(sub [,start [,end]]) -> int
```

Thus, we can build it ourselves:

```
def find_all(a_str, sub):
    start = 0
    while True:
        start = a_str.find(sub, start)
        if start == -1: return
        yield start
        start += len(sub) # use start += 1 to find overlapping matches

list(find_all('spam spam spam spam', 'spam')) # [0, 5, 10, 15]
```

No temporary strings or regexes required.

Comment: To get overlapping matches, it should suffice to replace `start += len(sub)` with `start += 1`.

Comment: I believe your previous comment should be a postscript in your answer.

Comment: Your code does not work for finding substr: "ATAT" in "GATATATGCATATACTT"

Comment: See the comment I made in addition. That is an example of an overlapping match.

Comment: To match the behaviour of `re.findall`, I'd recommend adding `len(sub) or 1` instead of `len(sub)`, otherwise this generator will never terminate on empty substring.

Comment: Personally I think that `a_str.find` should be replaced with `a_str.index` so that `return` isn't needed.

Answer (score 87):

Here's a (very inefficient) way to get *all* (i.e. even overlapping) matches:

```
>>> string = "test test test test"
>>> [i for i in range(len(string)) if string.startswith('test', i)]
[0, 5, 10, 15]
```

This solution also works for multi-word subwords.

```
s = "Find THIS SUB-WORD in this sentence with THIS SUB-WORD"
sub = "THIS SUB-WORD"
[i for i in range(len(s)) if s.startswith(sub, I)]
# [5, 41]
```

Comment: If we want to check many characters by using 1 for loop how can it be done? with this code, I'll have many for loop and the order of time is too high.

Comment: @thkala Very smart way of performing the operation without use of re module. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I think I like this answer more since it doesn't need the re module.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. The accepted answer doesn't work with multi-word subwords. For example, `THIS SUB-WORD` in this sentence `Find THIS SUB-WORD in this sentence with THIS SUB-WORD`.

Comment: This is not very efficient. The time complexity is the "haystack" length multiplied by the "needle" length. The efficient algorithm does it in "haystack" plus "needle" length time.

Answer (score 76):

Use [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer):

```
import re
sentence = input("Give me a sentence ")
word = input("What word would you like to find ")
for match in re.finditer(word, sentence):
    print (match.start(), match.end())
```

For `word = "this"` and `sentence = "this is a sentence this this"` this will yield the output:

```
(0, 4)
(19, 23)
(24, 28)
```

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out, that it works only for "non-overlapping matches", therefore won't work for: sentence="ababa" and word="aba"

Comment: This will fail if the word contains any characters that have a meaning in regex

Answer (score 67):

Again, old thread, but here's my solution using a **generator** and plain `str.find`.

```
def findall(p, s):
    '''Yields all the positions of
    the pattern p in the string s.'''
    i = s.find(p)
    while i != -1:
        yield i
        i = s.find(p, i+1)
```

#### Example

```
x = 'banananassantana'
[(i, x[i:i+2]) for i in findall('na', x)]
```

returns

```
[(2, 'na'), (4, 'na'), (6, 'na'), (14, 'na')]
```

Comment: this looks beautiful!

Comment: tested and it is twice faster than the `re.finditer` solution: `310 ns ± 5.35 ns per loop` for solution with `str.find` *vs* `799 ns ± 5.72 ns per loop` for solution with `re.finditer` (on my machine). Confirms what I've noticed in the past: built-in string methods are generally faster than regex (same for nested `str.replace` vs `re.sub`)

Comment: Prettiest solution.
Note that one can easily generalize by introducing optional parameter `overlapping=True` and replacing `i+1` by `i + (1 if overlapping else len(p))`.

Answer (score 25):

You can use `re.finditer()` for non-overlapping matches.

```
>>> import re
>>> aString = 'this is a string where the substring "is" is repeated several times'
>>> print [(a.start(), a.end()) for a in list(re.finditer('is', aString))]
[(2, 4), (5, 7), (38, 40), (42, 44)]
```

but **won't** work for:

```
In [1]: aString="ababa"

In [2]: print [(a.start(), a.end()) for a in list(re.finditer('aba', aString))]
Output: [(0, 3)]
```

Comment: Why make a list out of an iterator, it just slows the process.

Comment: aString VS astring ;)

Answer (score 22):

Come, let us recurse together.

```
def locations_of_substring(string, substring):
    """Return a list of locations of a substring."""

    substring_length = len(substring)    
    def recurse(locations_found, start):
        location = string.find(substring, start)
        if location != -1:
            return recurse(locations_found + [location], location+substring_length)
        else:
            return locations_found

    return recurse([], 0)

print(locations_of_substring('this is a test for finding this and this', 'this'))
# prints [0, 27, 36]
```

No need for regular expressions this way.

Comment: This code has several problems. Since it's working on open-ended data sooner or later you'll bump into `RecursionError` if there are many enough occurrences. Another one are two throw-away lists it creates on each iteration just for the sake of appending one element, which is very suboptimal for a string finding function, which possibly could be called a lot of times. Although sometimes recursive functions seem elegant and clear, they should be taken with caution.

Answer (score 13):

If you're just looking for a single character, this would work:

```
string = "dooobiedoobiedoobie"
match = 'o'
reduce(lambda count, char: count + 1 if char == match else count, string, 0)
# produces 7
```

Also,

```
string = "test test test test"
match = "test"
len(string.split(match)) - 1
# produces 4
```

My hunch is that neither of these (especially #2) is terribly performant.

Comment: gr8 solution .. i am impressed with use of .. split()

Answer (score 12):

this is an old thread but i got interested and wanted to share my solution.

```
def find_all(a_string, sub):
    result = []
    k = 0
    while k < len(a_string):
        k = a_string.find(sub, k)
        if k == -1:
            return result
        else:
            result.append(k)
            k += 1 #change to k += len(sub) to not search overlapping results
    return result
```

It should return a list of positions where the substring was found.
Please comment if you see an error or room for improvment.

Answer (score 9):

This does the trick for me using re.finditer

```
import re

text = 'This is sample text to test if this pythonic '\
       'program can serve as an indexing platform for '\
       'finding words in a paragraph. It can give '\
       'values as to where the word is located with the '\
       'different examples as stated'

#  find all occurances of the word 'as' in the above text

find_the_word = re.finditer('as', text)

for match in find_the_word:
    print('start {}, end {}, search string \'{}\''.
          format(match.start(), match.end(), match.group()))
```

Answer (score 7):

You can try :

```
import re
str1 = "This dress looks good; you have good taste in clothes."
substr = "good"
result = [_.start() for _ in re.finditer(substr, str1)]
# result = [17, 32]
```

Comment: This is no different from the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4664889/14363557).

Comment: @NatRiddle The presentation Mohammad wrote the answer in is a lot cleaner.  This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Regex is much heavier on CPU than the accepted answer

Answer (score 6):

This thread is a little old but this worked for me:

```
numberString = "onetwothreefourfivesixseveneightninefiveten"
testString = "five"

marker = 0
while marker < len(numberString):
    try:
        print(numberString.index("five",marker))
        marker = numberString.index("five", marker) + 1
    except ValueError:
        print("String not found")
        marker = len(numberString)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try :

```
>>> string = "test test test test"
>>> for index,value in enumerate(string):
    if string[index:index+(len("test"))] == "test":
        print index

0
5
10
15
```

Answer (score 4):

```
src = input() # we will find substring in this string
sub = input() # substring

res = []
pos = src.find(sub)
while pos != -1:
    res.append(pos)
    pos = src.find(sub, pos + 1)
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation

Answer (score 3):

When looking for a large amount of key words in a document, use [flashtext](https://flashtext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```
from flashtext import KeywordProcessor
words = ['test', 'exam', 'quiz']
txt = 'this is a test'
kwp = KeywordProcessor()
kwp.add_keywords_from_list(words)
result = kwp.extract_keywords(txt, span_info=True)
```

Flashtext runs faster than regex on large list of search words.

Answer (score 3):

This function does not look at all positions inside the string, it does not waste compute resources. My try:

```
def findAll(string,word):
    all_positions=[]
    next_pos=-1
    while True:
        next_pos=string.find(word,next_pos+1)
        if(next_pos<0):
            break
        all_positions.append(next_pos)
    return all_positions
```

to use it call it like this:

```
result=findAll('this word is a big word man how many words are there?','word')
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the most clean way of solution is **without** libraries and yields:

```py
def find_all_occurrences(string, sub):
    index_of_occurrences = []
    current_index = 0
    while True:
        current_index = string.find(sub, current_index)
        if current_index == -1:
            return index_of_occurrences
        else:
            index_of_occurrences.append(current_index)
            current_index += len(sub)

find_all_occurrences(string, substr)
```

**Note:** `find()` method returns `-1` when it can't find anything

Answer (score 2):

Whatever the solutions provided by others are completely based on the available method find() or any available methods.

> What is the core basic algorithm to find all the occurrences of a
>   substring in a string?

```
def find_all(string,substring):
    """
    Function: Returning all the index of substring in a string
    Arguments: String and the search string
    Return:Returning a list
    """
    length = len(substring)
    c=0
    indexes = []
    while c < len(string):
        if string[c:c+length] == substring:
            indexes.append(c)
        c=c+1
    return indexes
```

> You can also inherit str class to new class and can use this function
>   below.

```
class newstr(str):
def find_all(string,substring):
    """
    Function: Returning all the index of substring in a string
    Arguments: String and the search string
    Return:Returning a list
    """
    length = len(substring)
    c=0
    indexes = []
    while c < len(string):
        if string[c:c+length] == substring:
            indexes.append(c)
        c=c+1
    return indexes
```

Calling the method

> newstr.find_all('Do you find this answer helpful? then upvote
>   this!','this')

Answer (score 2):

This is solution of a similar question from hackerrank. I hope this could help you.

```py
import re
a = input()
b = input()
if b not in a:
    print((-1,-1))
else:
    #create two list as
    start_indc = [m.start() for m in re.finditer('(?=' + b + ')', a)]
    for i in range(len(start_indc)):
        print((start_indc[i], start_indc[i]+len(b)-1))
```

Output:

```
aaadaa
aa
(0, 1)
(1, 2)
(4, 5)
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to use without re(regex) then:

```
find_all = lambda _str,_w : [ i for i in range(len(_str)) if _str.startswith(_w,i) ]

string = "test test test test"
print( find_all(string, 'test') ) # >>> [0, 5, 10, 15]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that I came up with, using assignment expression (new feature since Python 3.8):

```py
string = "test test test test"
phrase = "test"
start = -1
result = [(start := string.find(phrase, start + 1)) for _ in range(string.count(phrase))]
```

Output:

```
[0, 5, 10, 15]
```

Answer (score 1):

The pythonic way would be:

```
mystring = 'Hello World, this should work!'
find_all = lambda c,s: [x for x in range(c.find(s), len(c)) if c[x] == s]

# s represents the search string
# c represents the character string

find_all(mystring,'o')    # will return all positions of 'o'

[4, 7, 20, 26] 
>>>
```

Comment: 1) How does this help a question that was answered 7 years ago? 2) [Using `lambda` this way is not Pythonic and goes against PEP8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38381663/1040092). 3) This doesn't provide the correct output for the OPs situation

Comment: Pythonic does not mean "Use as much features of python as you can think of"

Answer (score 1):

if you only want to use numpy here is a solution

```
import numpy as np

S= "test test test test"
S2 = 'test'
inds = np.cumsum([len(k)+len(S2) for k in S.split(S2)[:-1]])- len(S2)
print(inds)
```

Answer (score 0):

please look at below code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding:utf-8
'''黄哥Python'''


def get_substring_indices(text, s):
    result = [i for i in range(len(text)) if text.startswith(s, i)]
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    text = "How much wood would a wood chuck chuck if a wood chuck could chuck wood?"
    s = 'wood'
    print get_substring_indices(text, s)
```

Comment: simple and best answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_index(string, let):
    enumerated = [place  for place, letter in enumerate(string) if letter == let]
    return enumerated
```

for example :

```
find_index("hey doode find d", "d")
```

returns:

```
[4, 7, 13, 15]
```

Comment: Have you actually read the question? Try `print(find_index('test test test test', 'test'))` which is the example the op gave.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what OP asked but you could also use the [split function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to get a list of where all the substrings *don't* occur. OP didn't specify the end goal of the code but if your goal is to remove the substrings anyways then this could be a simple one-liner. There are probably more efficient ways to do this with larger strings; regular expressions would be preferable in that case

```py
# Extract all non-substrings
s = "an-example-string"
s_no_dash = s.split('-')
# >>> s_no_dash
# ['an', 'example', 'string']

# Or extract and join them into a sentence
s_no_dash2 = ' '.join(s.split('-'))
# >>> s_no_dash2
# 'an example string'
```

Did a brief skim of other answers so apologies if this is already up there.

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_substring(string, sub_string):
    c=0
    for i in range(0,len(string)-2):
        if string[i:i+len(sub_string)] == sub_string:
            c+=1
    return c

if __name__ == '__main__':
    string = input().strip()
    sub_string = input().strip()
    
    count = count_substring(string, sub_string)
    print(count)
```

Comment: Replace line 3, with: `for i in range(0,len(string)+1-len(sub_string)):`

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

I runned in the same problem and did this:

```
hw = 'Hello oh World!'
list_hw = list(hw)
o_in_hw = []

while True:
    o = hw.find('o')
    if o != -1:
        o_in_hw.append(o)
        list_hw[o] = ' '
        hw = ''.join(list_hw)
    else:
        print(o_in_hw)
        break
```

Im pretty new at coding so you can probably simplify it (and if planned to used continuously of course make it a function).

All and all it works as intended for what i was doing.

Edit: Please consider this is for single characters only, and it will change your variable, so you have to create a copy of the string in a new variable to save it, i didnt put it in the code cause its easy and its only to show how i made it work.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers so far imply inefficient solutions that take `O(n*m)` time, where `n` is the "haystack" length and `m` is the "needle" length. Though I'm not sure whether it's true for the [regular expression solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4664889/1118709).

The problem can be solved in an `O(n+m)` time using a [Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) version that doesn't stop after an occurrence is found:

```py
# Not necessary to comprehend, just copy to your code
def findAll(haystack: str, needle: str):
    n = len(haystack)
    m = len(needle)
    # Key - needle prefix length,
    # Value - the length of the longest other needle prefix that is also a suffix of this prefix.
    longestPrefixSuffix = [0] * m
    length = 0
    suffixEnd = 1 # Last index

    while suffixEnd < m - 1:
        if needle[length] == needle[suffixEnd]:
            length += 1
            suffixEnd += 1
            longestPrefixSuffix[suffixEnd] = length
        elif length > 0:
            # Since needle[0:length] == needle[suffixEnd-length:suffixEnd],
            # needle[0:longestPrefixSuffix[length]] == needle[suffixEnd-longestPrefixSuffix[length]:suffixEnd]
            length = longestPrefixSuffix[length]
            # Try to continue the equal substrings with the shorter prefix
        else:
            suffixEnd += 1
    
    i = 0 # haystack index
    j = 0 # needle index

    while i <= n - m:
        if haystack[i + j] == needle[j]:
            if j + 1 < m:
                j += 1
                continue
            yield i
        if j > 0:
            # Move i to the end of the compared region,
            # unless a part of needle is a prefix of needle
            i = i + j - longestPrefixSuffix[j]
            j = longestPrefixSuffix[j]
        else:
            i += 1
            j = 0

print(list(findAll("test test test test", "test"))) # [0, 5, 10, 15]
```

This algorithm is used inside the built-in `find` method. I wish the `findAll` function is also built-in.

Answer (score -1):

By slicing we find all the combinations possible and append them in a list and find the number of times it occurs using `count` function

```
s=input()
n=len(s)
l=[]
f=input()
print(s[0])
for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range(1,n+1):
        l.append(s[i:j])
if f in l:
    print(l.count(f))
```

Comment: When `s="test test test test"` and `f="test"` your code prints `4`, but OP expected `[0,5,10,15]`

Comment: Have written for a single word will update the code

Answer (score -1):

To find all the occurence of a character in a give string and return as a dictionary
*eg: hello
result :
**{'h':1, 'e':1, 'l':2, 'o':1}***

```
def count(string):
   result = {}
   if(string):
     for i in string:
       result[i] = string.count(i)
     return result
   return {}
```

or else you do like this

```
from collections import Counter

   def count(string):
      return Counter(string)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this it worked for me !

```
x=input('enter the string')
y=input('enter the substring')
z,r=x.find(y),x.rfind(y)
while z!=r:
        print(z,r,end=' ')
        z=z+len(y)
        r=r-len(y)
        z,r=x.find(y,z,r),x.rfind(y,z,r)
```

Answer (score -3):

You can easily use:

```
string.count('test')!
```

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/count

Cheers!

Comment: this should be the answer

Comment: The string count() method returns the number of occurrences of a substring in the given string. Not their location.

Comment: this doesnt satisfty all cases, s = 'banana' , sub = 'ana'. Sub occurs in this situation twice but doing s.sub('ana') would return 1