# Finding various string repeats in python in next 10 characters

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

So I'm working on a problem where I have to find various string repeats after encountering an initial string, say we take ACTGAC so the data file has sequences that look like:

AAACTGACACCATCGATCAGAACCTGA

So in that string once we find ACTGAC then I need to analyze the next 10 characters for the string repeats which go by some rules. I have the rules coded but can anyone show me how once I find the string that I need, I can make a substring for the next ten characters to analyze. I know that str.partition function can do that once I find the string, and then the [1:10] can get the next ten characters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost have it already (but note that indexes start counting from *zero* in Python).

The `partition` method will split a string into `head, separator, tail`, based on the first occurence of `separator`.

So you just need to take a slice of the first ten characters of the `tail`:

```
>>> data = 'AAACTGACACCATCGATCAGAACCTGA'
>>> head, sep, tail = data.partition('ACTGAC')
>>> tail[:10]
'ACCATCGATC'
```

Python allows you to leave out the start-index in slices (in defaults to zero - the start of the string), and also the end-index (it defaults to the length of the string).

Note that you could also do the whole operation in one line, like this:

```
>>> data.partition('ACTGAC')[2][:10]
'ACCATCGATC'
```

Comment: Just bear in mind that string.partition() "Split the string at the **first** occurrence of sep". If there are multiple cases of separator or overlapping separators, have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-python

Answer (score 0):

So, based on marcog's answer in [Find all occurrences of a substring in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-python) , I propose:

```
>>> import re
>>> data = 'AAACTGACACCATCGATCAGAACCTGAACTGACTGACAAA'
>>> sep = 'ACTGAC'
>>> [data[m.start()+len(sep):][:10] for m in re.finditer('(?=%s)'%sep, data)]
['ACCATCGATC', 'TGACAAA', 'AAA']
```