# Using BeautifulSoup to search HTML for string

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup to look for user-entered strings on a specific page.
For example, I want to see if the string 'Python' is located on the page: http://python.org

When I used:
`find_string = soup.body.findAll(text='Python')`,
`find_string` returned `[]`

But when I used:
`find_string = soup.body.findAll(text=re.compile('Python'), limit=1)`,
`find_string` returned `[u'Python Jobs']` as expected

What is the difference between these two statements that makes the second statement work when there are more than one instances of the word to be searched?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

The following line is looking for the **exact** NavigableString 'Python':

```
>>> soup.body.findAll(text='Python')
[]
```

Note that the following NavigableString is found:

```
>>> soup.body.findAll(text='Python Jobs') 
[u'Python Jobs']
```

Note this behaviour:

```
>>> import re
>>> soup.body.findAll(text=re.compile('^Python$'))
[]
```

So your regexp is looking for an occurrence of 'Python' not the exact match to the NavigableString 'Python'.

Comment: Is is possible to get the parent tag of a specific text?

Comment: @Samay `soup.find(text='Python Jobs').parent` — from docs: ["Going up"](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#going-up)

Answer (score 38):

`text='Python'` searches for elements that have the exact text you provided:

```
import re
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

html = """<p>exact text</p>
   <p>almost exact text</p>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print soup(text='exact text')
print soup(text=re.compile('exact text'))
```

#### Output

```
[u'exact text']
[u'exact text', u'almost exact text']
```

"To see if the string 'Python' is located on the page http://python.org":

```
import urllib2
html = urllib2.urlopen('http://python.org').read()
print 'Python' in html # -> True
```

If you need to find a position of substring within a string you could do `html.find('Python')`.

Comment: Is it possible to find all occurrences of the string Python, not just one?

Comment: @Timo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring

Comment: [m.start() for m in re.finditer('test',soup')] ? I am lost..

Comment: @Timo copy the code from [the accepted answer to the StackOverflow question  I've linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4664889/4279). Make sure the code fragment works in your environment. Start changing it to your task (one simple change at a time). Once it breaks (when it does something unexpected for you), use it as [the minimal reproducible code example to ask a new StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 13):

In addition to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8936235/). You can use a `lambda` instead of `regex`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<p>test python</p>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

print(soup(text="python"))
print(soup(text=lambda t: "python" in t.text))
```

Output:

```
[]
['test python']
```

Answer (score 3):

I have not used BeuatifulSoup but maybe the following can help in some tiny way.

```
import re
import urllib2
stuff = urllib2.urlopen(your_url_goes_here).read()  # stuff will contain the *entire* page

# Replace the string Python with your desired regex
results = re.findall('(Python)',stuff)

for i in results:
    print i
```

I'm not suggesting this is a replacement but maybe you can glean some value in the concept until a direct answer comes along.

Comment: Googlers see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34475051/need-to-install-urllib2-for-python-3-5-1 for an modern update.