# How to find a particular word in html page through beautiful soup in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I want to find how many times a particular word has come in a web page through beautiful soup within that html text ?
I tried out the `findAll` function but finds only words within a particular tag like `soup.body.findAll` will find the particular word within the body tag but I want it to search that word within all tags that in in the html text.
Also once I find that word I need to create a list of word just coming before and after that word, can someone please help me how to do so ? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using BeautifulSoup to search html for string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936030/using-beautifulsoup-to-search-html-for-string)

Comment: No it's not a duplicate, I checked

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [newest BeautifulSoup 4 api](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-recursive-argument) you can use `recursive` keyword to find the text in the whole tree. You will have strings that then you can operator on and seperate the words.

Here is a complete example:

```
import bs4
import re

data = '''
<html>
<body>
<div>today is a sunny day</div>
<div>I love when it's sunny outside</div>
Call me sunny
<div>sunny is a cool word sunny</div>
</body>
</html>
'''

searched_word = 'sunny'

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
results = soup.body.find_all(string=re.compile('.*{0}.*'.format(searched_word)), recursive=True)

print 'Found the word "{0}" {1} times\n'.format(searched_word, len(results))

for content in results:
    words = content.split()
    for index, word in enumerate(words):
        # If the content contains the search word twice or more this will fire for each occurence
        if word == searched_word:
            print 'Whole content: "{0}"'.format(content)
            before = None
            after = None
            # Check if it's a first word
            if index != 0:
                before = words[index-1]
            # Check if it's a last word
            if index != len(words)-1:
                after = words[index+1]
            print '\tWord before: "{0}", word after: "{1}"'.format(before, after)
```

it outputs:

```
Found the word "sunny" 4 times

Whole content: "today is a sunny day"
    Word before: "a", word after: "day"
Whole content: "I love when it's sunny outside"
    Word before: "it's", word after: "outside"
Whole content: "
Call me sunny
"
    Word before: "me", word after: "None"
Whole content: "sunny is a cool word sunny"
    Word before: "None", word after: "is"
Whole content: "sunny is a cool word sunny"
    Word before: "word", word after: "None"
```

[Also see here's string keyword reference](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-string-argument)

Comment: results = soup.body.find_all(string=searched_word, recursive=true)
NameError: name 'true' is not defined

Comment: I have downloaded http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/download/    version  4.3/

Comment: I updated the answer with the complete, working example, please check it again

Comment: I am getting "Found the word "sunny" 0 times" r u using python 2.7.3 ?  I just copy pasted ur example code

Comment: It seems the ```string``` keyword was added in version 4.4, so use that or change ```soup.body.find_all(string=...)``` to ```soup.body.find_all(text=...)``` (different keyword for 4.3 and before)

Comment: Ok lemme download 4.4 then and check

Comment: Thanks a lot, Tht issue was with the version. Now I can append these words come before and after the required word ! Thank you once again. I was so troubled, u solved it so easily :)

Comment: This seems to go bazerk at scale.. I'm working with a SoupObject and trying to find all of the things that come after `aria-labelledby` or have a string like `"aria-labelledby="listing_"`. Do you know how I would adjust this or a different method to find what I am looking for? Here is a sample page with my function: https://gist.github.com/gumdropsteve/8268ddb157a8b987265d6b29a86d6dda