# Parsing child value by sibling and parent using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, parsing

I have a problem with extracting **I-want-ya** text from:

```
<div class="field">
   <div class="labelx"><a class="clickme" href="#h_group123" rel="#h_group123" title="Group">* Group</a></div>
   <div class="input">I-want-ya</div>
</div>
```

The soulution up to the point:

```
browser = robobrowser.RoboBrowser(parser='html.parser')
browser.open(url)
browser = browser.parsed
soup = BeautifulSoup(str(browser), 'html.parser')

parsed_value = soup.select('div.labelx  + .input)
```

Is there a chance to get **I-want-ya** value:

```
  <div class="input">I-want-ya</div>
```

By the sibling  with tag div that specifically has class="labelx" and child a with attribute title="Group"?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936030/using-beautifulsoup-to-search-html-for-string

Comment: `soup.find('div', {'class': 'input'}).text`

Comment: @DarthOpto: That question doesn't seem to involve searching by sibling, does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED: Now accounts for multiple matches

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = '''<div class="field">
   <div class="labelx"><a class="clickme" href="#h_group123" rel="#h_group123" title="Group">* Group</a></div>
   <div class="input">I-want-ya</div>
   <div class="labelx"><a class="clickme" href="#h_group123" rel="#h_group123" title="Group">* Group</a></div>
   <div class="input">I-want-you-2</div>
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser')

divs = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'labelx'})
for div in divs:
    try:
        div.find('a', {'title': 'Group'})
        print(div.findNext('div', {'class': 'input'}).text)
    except:
        print('No match.')
```

Gives:

```
I-want-ya
I-want-you-2
```

Comment: Needed only to add conditional statement: if div.find('a', {'title': 'Group}): and everything works perfectly. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that I understand you correctly:

- Find the `div` element with the desired `class`.
- Ask for all of its siblings, get the first of them, then get the `text` of that one.

---

```
>>> HTML = '''\
... <div class="field">
...     <div class="labelx"><a class="clickme" href="#h_group123" rel="#h_group123" title="Group">* Group</a></div>
...     <div class="input">I-want-ya</div>
... </div>'''
>>> import bs4
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(HTML, 'lxml')
>>> first_sib_div = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'labelx'})
>>> first_sib_div.fetchNextSiblings()[0].text
'I-want-ya'
```

Edit: This is what it should have been.

```
>>> HTML = '''\
... <div class="field">
...     <div class="labelx"><a class="clickme" href="#h_group123" rel="#h_group123" title="Group">* Group</a></div>
...     <div class="input">I-want-ya</div>
... </div>'''
>>> import bs4
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(HTML, 'lxml')
>>> first_div_link = soup.select('div.labelx > a[title="Group"]')[0]
>>> first_div_link.findParent().fetchNextSiblings()[0].text
'I-want-ya'
```

Addendum: Added in response to question from rahlf23.

```
>>> s = '''\
... <div class="field">
...     <div class="labelx"><a class="clickme" href="#h_group123" rel="#h_group123" title="Group">* Group</a></div>
...         <div class="input">I-want-ya</div>
...     <div class="labelx"><a class="clickme" href="#h_group123" rel="#h_group123" title="Group">* Group</a></div>     
...         <div class="input">I-want-ya-too</div>
... </div>'''
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(s, 'lxml')
>>> for item in soup.select('div.labelx > a[title="Group"]'):
...     item.findParent().fetchNextSiblings()[0].text
...     
'I-want-ya'
'I-want-ya-too'
```

Comment: This does not account for the requirement that it has a child `a` tag with `title="Group"`

Comment: Works on my end! Curious for myself here, is there a `select_all()` equivalent that would work on the HTML sample I included in my answer?

Comment: @rahlf23: Possibly like what I added in the addendum?