# How to find element based on text ignore child tags in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am looking for a solution using Python and BeautifulSoup to find an element based on the inside text. For example:

```
<div> <b>Ignore this text</b>Find based on this text </div>
```

How can I find this div? Thanks for you helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.find` with the `text` argument and then use `findParent` to the parent element.

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s="""<div> <b>Ignore this text</b>Find based on this text </div>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser')
t = soup.find(text="Find based on this text ") 
print(t.findParent())
```

**Output:**

```
<div> <b>Ignore this text</b>Find based on this text </div>
```

Comment: If the text appears more than one, can I find all the divs that contains the text?

Comment: Sure. You can use `soup.find_all(text="")`

Comment: Can I specify the find_all to find div tags only?

Comment: Note that `findParent()` is bs3 syntax. For bs4 it's `find_parent()`, or simply use the property `.parent`. `find_parent()` is generally used when you need to find a specific parent (ancestor) tag. For example, `find_parent('a')`.

Answer (score 0):

try it , it is like example but it works

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html="""
<div> <b>Ignore this text</b>Find based on this text </div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')                                                                                                                                                

s = soup.find('div')

for child in s.find_all('b'):
    child.decompose()

print(s.get_text())
```

**Output**

```
 Find based on this text
```

Comment: I think the question is asking for text search like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/8936235/986546