# How to find parent tags of an element with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to know if its possible to me get, using beautiful soup, a few lines up  of html line:

```html
<tr id="12590559" class="">
<td>
<span class="he16-1 tip-top" title="Cracker"></span>
</td>
<td>
cracker.crc
</td>
```

In that example I want to extract the id but with the tittle information using:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(lista.content, "lxml")
id = soup.find(attrs={"title": "Cracker"})
```

I can get the

```html
<span class="he16-1 tip-top" title="Cracker"></span>
```

but I want to get also the `id`. Can I use the `BeautifulSoup` to get a few lines up?

Comment: please mark answer as accepted if it correctly solved your issue :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use **[BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-parents-and-find-parent)**'s `find_parent` /`find_parents` method.

pass `tr` as parent search item and `['id']` will print id value

```
id.find_parent('tr')['id']

>> '12590559'
```

Comment: But i want to get the id of that block cause it hes from cracker.crc not the other blocks cause they are the same but with different name, anyway thanks for the help :)

Comment: Like in the page i have more code like that and i want to get that piece cause he have cracker.crc

Comment: Your html block has only one id tag and that's with td. Other blocks don't have id tag.

Comment: Thats not the full html thats just a block, i want to find thaht block by the text (Cracker.crc)

Comment: [search by text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936030/using-beautifulsoup-to-search-html-for-string)

Comment: yup but if i search by text it will find the text and not the id and i want to find the "block" with the text and then get the id...

Comment: Your question dint mention searching by text , but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50459203/how-to-find-element-based-on-text-ignore-child-tags-in-beautifulsoup?noredirect=1&lq=1) might be useful

Comment: Finally ty for the answer, i put find(text="Cracker") then findparent like you do and it works ty!