# Python BeautifulSoup find_all - how to search the html for a string, ignoring all spaces and non breaking spaces in the html?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using Python BeautifulSoup to extract the risk factor section from 10K filings (so I need to locate where the section begins and ends). For example:

https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1321502/000143774910004615/andain_10k-123106.htm

To get this element:

ITEM 1A.  RISK FACTORS

I would like to adapt something like this:

`my_text = soup.find_all(string=["ITEM1A.RISKFACTORS", "RISKFACTORS"])`

To also capture anything that, once stripped of all spaces before and after (and possibly in-between words too), non-breaking spaces, and any other formatting that gets in the way, **exactly** matches one of my strings ("ITEM1A.RISKFACTORS", "RISKFACTORS").

**I want:**
`"Item 1A. Risk Factors"`
`"Risk        Factors"`
`"      Risk   Factors"`
`"Risk&nbsp;Factors"`
`"Item 1A.\xa0Risk Factors"`

**I don't want:**
`"We have a number of Risk Factors."`

Ideally I'd like to avoid regex, if there is maybe some kind of "stripped=True" argument I can use with find_all that'd be better, but if regex is needed please help me write it! Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Thanks Some written code, url, ... would be cool.

Comment: Thank you! I've edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the easiest way to do it is to use REGex.
You can remove spacing between words like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1546244/9231525):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(' +', ' ', 'The     quick brown    fox')
'The quick brown fox'
```

To fix encoding you can try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7222658/9231525):

```
r = urllib.urlopen('http://www.elnorte.ec/')
x = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(r.read)
r.close()

print(x.prettify('latin-1'))
```

And to search for those strings I would also suggest using regex, and that would look something along those [lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8936232/9231525)

```
print(soup(text=re.compile('exact text')))
```

If you search for it won't only find `"exact text"` but also `"almost exact text"`