# Get substring with code from different strings

Tags: python

I'm working on a web scraper. Among the fields it scrapes there is a Description tag like this one, different for each product:

```
<div class="productDescription" style="overflow: hidden; display: block;">
Black Tshirt
<br>
<br>
REF.: V23T87C88EC
<br>
<br>
COMPOSIÇÃO:
<br>
90% Poliamida
</div>
```

I can get the content of the description tag without problems, but I also need to get the value of REF inside the description (V23T87C88EC for this example).

The problem is this description is always different for all products, HOWEVER there is ALWAYS a "REF.: XXXXXXXXX" substring in there.
The length of the REF id can change, and it can be anywhere in the string.
What's the best way to always get the REF id?

Comment: I'd say a lookbehind regexp would do the trick: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-regex-lookbehind/  : try this pattern r"(?<=REF.: )\w+"

Comment: You can use `regex` to extract the string that comes after REF.:

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936030/using-beautifulsoup-to-search-html-for-string

Comment: Perfect! Thanks @Swifty, that does the trick. I'll accepr your answer if you post it...

Comment: I'll do that right now then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a regex (read more about regex: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) :

```
html = '''
<div class="productDescription" style="overflow: hidden; display: block;">
Black Tshirt
<br>
<br>
REF.: V23T87C88EC
<br>
<br>
COMPOSIÇÃO:
<br>
90% Poliamida
</div>
'''

import re

myref = re.search (r"(?<=REF.: )\w+", html)[0]

print(myref)

# V23T87C88EC
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution is the following:

```
html = """<div class="productDescription" style="overflow: hidden;  
display: block;">
Black Tshirt
<br>
<br>
REF.: V23T87C88EC
<br>
<br>
COMPOSIÇÃO:
<br>
90% Poliamida
</div>"""

import re

pattern = re.compile(r'REF\.: (.+?)$')

found = pattern.findall(html)
```

> Returns ['V23T87C88EC']

[REGEX DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/WNskmN/1)