# Finding the second, third, or further times that a string of characters occurs in a string in python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, substring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find all occurrences of a substring in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-python)

I have a string of numbers and am trying to find each time a certain string of numbers occurs in the string.

I know if I use, for example: `numString.find(str)` that it will tell me the first time it occurs. Is there anyway to modify this statement to find each time that str occurs, not just the first?

Comment: Alright, thanks. I haven't yet learned about regular expressions so I will have to write some code to get around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, is regexp is out of the question, consider this generator code:

```
def find_all(target, substring):
    current_pos = target.find(substring)
    while current_pos != -1:
        yield current_pos
        current_pos += len(substring)
        current_pos = target.find(substring, current_pos)
```

We use 'find' optional argument of setting the start index of the search, and every time use the last one found, plus the length of the sub-string (so we do't get the same result every time).
If you want to get **overlapping matches**, use `+ 1` and not `len(substring)`.

You can `'list(find_all('abbccbb', 'bb'))'` to get an actual list of indexs.

Just a side note: generators (aka, the `yield` keyword) are more memory efficient than plain lists, and while loops have far less overhead than recursion (and are also much easier to read if you are a human being).

Comment: This is the solution I was about to write, with the exception of defaulting to simply incrementing the current_pos, in order to handle matches that overlap, as you mention. The performance penalty is not large :-)

Answer (score 1):

you can use recursion:

`find()`uses a second optional argument, which provides the `starting index` for search, so with every iteration you can set that argument to current value returned by `find()+1`

```
>>> strs='aabbaabbaabbaabbaa'
>>> def ret(x,a,lis=None,start=0):
    if lis is None:
        lis=[]
    if x.find(a,start)!=-1:
         index=x.find(a,start)
        lis.append(index)
        return ret(x,a,lis=lis,start=index+1)
    else: return lis

>>> ret(strs,'aa')
[0, 4, 8, 12, 16]

>>> ret(strs,'bb')
[2, 6, 10, 14]
>>>
```

Comment: Python has a maximum recursion depth of 1000 by default, so this will fail with a `RuntimeError` if there are 1000 or more matches. Also, function calling is expensive, and it's trivial to rewrite this as a `while` loop, thus making it more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient way of doing it .. but it's a one-liner!! If that counts .... :)

```
>>> s = "akjdsfaklafdjfjad"
>>> [n for n in set([s.find('a',x) for x in range(len(s))]) if n >= 0]
[0, 9, 6, 15]
```