# Find all the occurrences of a character in a string

Tags: python, string

I am trying to find all the occurences of "|" in a string.

```
def findSectionOffsets(text):
    startingPos = 0
    endPos = len(text)

    for position in text.find("|",startingPos, endPos):
        print position
        endPos = position
```

But I get an error:

```
    for position in text.find("|",startingPos, endPos):
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: `text.find("|",startingPos, endPos)` is giving you a single `int` value, which the for loop is iterating on...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-python

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The function:

```
def findOccurrences(s, ch):
    return [i for i, letter in enumerate(s) if letter == ch]


findOccurrences(yourString, '|')
```

will return a list of the indices of `yourString` in which the `|` occur.

Comment: how does that loop work?  `i for i, letter in enumerate(s) if letter == ch`.

Comment: @Goodword:This answer uses a *list comprehension*;  see the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: The function is spelled wrong on the definition line. It should be "def findOccurrences" with two r's.

Answer (score 18):

if you want index of all occurrences of `|` character in a string you can do this

```
import re
str = "aaaaaa|bbbbbb|ccccc|dddd"
indexes = [x.start() for x in re.finditer('\|', str)]
print(indexes) # <-- [6, 13, 19]
```

also you can do

```
indexes = [x for x, v in enumerate(str) if v == '|']
print(indexes) # <-- [6, 13, 19]
```

Comment: thanks. good answer - fyi, you shouldn't use `str` as a variable name. it overwrites the native function

Answer (score 3):

```
import re
def findSectionOffsets(text)
    for i,m in enumerate(re.finditer('\|',text)) :
        print i, m.start(), m.end()
```

Answer (score 2):

text.find() only returns the first result, and then you need to set the new starting position based on that. So like this:

```
def findSectionOffsets(text):
    startingPos = 0

    position = text.find("|", startingPos):
    while position > -1:
        print position
        startingPos = position + 1
        position = text.find("|", startingPos)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is easier to use regular expressions here;

```
import re

def findSectionOffsets(text):
    for m in re.finditer('\|', text):
        print m.start(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

If `text` is the string that you want to count how many `"|"` it contains, the following line of code returns the count:

```
len(text.split("|"))-1
```

Note: This will also work for searching sub-strings.

Answer (score 1):

`text.find` returns an integer (the index at which the desired string is found), so you can run for loop over it.

I suggest:

```
def findSectionOffsets(text):
    indexes = []
    startposition = 0

    while True:
        i = text.find("|", startposition)
        if i == -1: break
        indexes.append(i)
        startposition = i + 1

    return indexes
```

Comment: I don't think this will work, because startposition never changes - it'll loop for ever if there's a match.