# making str.find a function

Tags: python

I have been trying to create the str.find method a function for a lesson I am doing and I am not quite sure how it is done. If anyone can help me please do. I am running on python 2.7 if that helps. I am trying to find a subsequence in a larger sequence and how many times it appears in the sequence. 
ex. ACAAGATGCCATTGTCCCCCGGCCTCCTGCTGCTGCTGCTCTCCGGGGCCACGGCCACCGCTGCCCTGCCCCTGGAGGGTGGCCCCACCGGCCGAGACAGCGAGCATATGCAGGAAGCGGCAGGAATAAGGAAAAGCAGCCTCCTGACTTTCCTCGCTTGGTGGTTTGAGTGGACCTCCCAGGCCAGTGCCGGGCCCCTCATAGGAGAGGAAGCTCGGGAGGTGGCCAGGCGGCAGGAAGGCGCACCCCCCCAGCAATCCGCGCGCCGGGACAGAATGCCCTGCAGGAACTTCTTCTGGAAGACCTTCTCCTCCTGCAAATAAAACCTCACCCATGAATGCTCACGCAAGTTTAATTACAGACCTGAA

and now I must find where each occurrence of TTG is in commas. again I really appreciate the help

Comment: Are you looking to extend string so that it has a find method or are you trying just to find something in a string? Also, possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-python

Comment: As a hint, look at `startswith` function (http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html)

Comment: def find(x):
    return x.find()
^^ is what i was hoping it would be 
i need to use a function that can act as the str.find method to help me find all the places a substring is found in the original more lengthy string. sorry I was not so clear

Answer (score 4):

Methods in Python can be turned into ordinary functions by accessing the method through the class.

```
>>> 'abc'.find('b')
1
>>> str.find('abc', 'b')
1
```

Comment: would this be able to work if i need to find a substring in a string and how many times it appears?

Comment: Read the [Python Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods).  You can repeatedly call the function with a different offset.

Answer (score 1):

Python's `string.find` method is implemented by the function [`fastsearch` in `stringlib/fastsearch.h`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/daa1a7a51319/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h). This function implements a version of the well known [Boyer–Moore algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm).