# Python Finding All Open Parentheses in a String

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find the position of all open parentheses in a string. Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4664889/2327821), I am able to find the positions of letters, but I cannot find the position of parentheses. For example, `l = [3, 4]`, but when I try and find all `(` I get `error: unbalanced parenthesis`.

```
import re

s = "(Hello("
l = [m.start() for m in re.finditer('l', s)]
openp = [m.start() for m in re.finditer('(', s)]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In regular expressions `(` is a special character that denotes the beginning of a group.  To match a literal `(` you will need to either escape it with a backslash or put it into a character class:

```
openp = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(r'\(', s)]
```

... or:

```
openp = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(r'[(]', s)]
```

As a more generic solution, you can use [`re.escape()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape) to automatically escape a string so that all characters are interpreted literally.  For example:

```
substr_to_find = '('
substr_locs = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(re.escape(substr_to_find), s)]
```

As pointed out by DSM in comments, in this situation you could also use a very readable list comprehension instead of regex:

```
openp = [i for i, c in enumerate(s) if c == "("]
```

Comment: For the non-regex approach, I think `[i for i,c in enumerate(s) if c == "("]` is easier to read.