# Use string.find() for multiple cases

Tags: python

For `.find()` how would you find the cases in multiple places?

For example:

```
string = 'banana'

string.find('na')
```

I want it to return `[3, 5]` by creating a blank list and appending it. How would I go about this?

Comment: Check out this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-python

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re
>>> [m.start()+1 for m in re.finditer('na', 'banana')]
[3, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4664889/3290121), you can do:

```
>>> import re
>>> [m.start() for m in re.finditer('na', 'banana')]
[2, 4]
```

In most programming languages, you start counts with 0, not 1, that's why the `"na"`s start at 2 and 4, not 3 and 5.