# Find all the occurrences of a character in a given list of string in python language

Tags: python, list

this is example what i'm looking for.

Example:

```
Input: ['234','34','22','7','99'] 

0:0
1:0
2:3
3:2
4:2
5:0
6:0
7:1
8:0
9:2
```

Comment: Have you tried yourself?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`joined` joins all the chars into one string `"2343422799"` 
 Then  we loop through the digits `0-9` and use the `count` method to see how many times each digit appears in the string and print the digit and the count using string formatting.

```
 l=['234','34','22','7','99']     
joined="".join(l) # joins all the chars into one string "2343422799"
for ch in range(10): # go through digits from 0-9
    print "{}:{}".format(ch,joined.count(str(ch))) 
0:0
1:0
2:3
3:2
4:2
5:0
6:0
7:1
8:0
9:2
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Pure code is good, but code + explanation is much better