# How do I make a loop continue down a string?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
st = "abXabXAbX"
ch = "A"
st = st.lower()
ch = ch.lower()


for i in st:
    if (i==ch):
       print st.find(i)
```

I am trying to position of the character "ch" in uppercase and lower case in the string "st". The for loop gets stuck at detecting the first "a", how do I get the loop to move on check the rest of the string?

Comment: The loop is not “stuck”, you are just using the `find` function in a weird way.

Comment: Have a look at some of the solutions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-python)

Comment: If you've found any of the answers below useful, please accept one of them.

Answer (score 1):

The for loop isn't stuck, but advancing as it should. You think it's stuck because [`find`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find) returns the **first** occurence of the item it looks for. It always encounters it at index 0, so your code prints 0, 0, 0.

For this to run, you can use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to keep track of the index of the letter:

```
for i, ltr in enumerate(st):
    if (ltr==ch):
       print i
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> st = "abXabXAbX".lower()
>>> ch = "A".lower()
>>> [ ix for ix,item in enumerate(st) if item == ch]
[0, 3, 6]
```

Comment: You don't need the `' '.join(st).split()` - you can just do `enumerate(st)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
st = "abXabXAbX"
ch = "A"
st = st.lower()
ch = ch.lower()
pos = st.find(ch)
print(pos)

while pos >= 0:
    pos=st.find(ch,pos+1)
    if pos>-1:
        print(pos)
```

this will give you all positions

Comment: more elegant w/o the first print, and then `while pos>=0: print(pos); pos = st.find(ch, pos+1`