# Boolean expression with strings

Tags: python, string, count

How can I make a boolean expression when I need to check if one string is simply another string repeated multiple times.

For example:

```
is_periodiek('ABABABABABABABABABABABABABABABABABAB', 'AB')
>>> True

is_periodiek('ABABABABABABABABABABABABABABABABABAB', 'ABA')
>>> False

is_periodiek('ABABABABABABABABABABABABABABABABABAB', 'ABAB')
>>> True
```

I think I need to make a 'for' loop but it never found the solution.

Comment: Doesn't this answer your question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-python

Comment: did you mean the string appears Consecutive  by *mutiple times* ?

Comment: yes that is what I mean. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: are you counting overlapping?

Comment: No you need to take the second string and place it in the first string. If you can do it like 5 times and you used all the elements from the first string it returns True. But if you preserve elements from the first string and you can't continue because it's too short in comparison to the second string you need to return False.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you wand the pattern appears Consecutive , you can `split` your string by pattern , if you get a list with empty strings , you can return `True` , else `False` :

```
>>> s='ABABABABABABABABABABABABABABABABABAB'
>>> s.split('AB')
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
>>> s.split('ABA')
['', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B']
>>> s.split('ABAB')
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

so as says in comment you can get that boolean value with this compare :

```
>>> len(''.join(s.split('AB'))) == 0
True
>>> len(''.join(s.split('ABA'))) == 0
False
>>> len(''.join(s.split('ABAB'))) == 0
True
```

Also you can use it in a function :

```
def IsConsecutive(string,pattern):
    return len(''.join(string.split(pattern))) == 0
```

Comment: based on that, `len(''.join(s.split('AB'))) == 0` would be a matching test.

Answer (score 1):

```
is_periodiek = lambda text, sub: not text.replace(sub, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with a recursive lambda:

```
is_periodiek = lambda x, y: x == y or (is_periodiek(x[len(y):], y) and x.find(y) == 0)
```