# IndexError: list index out of range Error. (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I submit the following code:

```
data = open("DNA Motif.txt", "r")
lines = data.readlines()
large = list(lines[0])
small = list(lines[1])
list = []
counts = []

print large

for first in range(0, len(large)):
    list = []
    if large[first] == small[0]:
        for other in range(0, len(small)):
            if small[other] == large[first + other]:
                list.append(large[first + other])
            if list == small:
                counts.append(str(first + 1))
```

With the following data set:

```
TTGCGTTTCGCGTTTCTCCGTTGCGTTTCTAGCGTTTCCAGGCGACCGCGTTTCGCGTTTCAGCGTTTCGCGTTTCGCGTTTCGCGTTTCCCCGGGGGCGTTTCGCGTTTCGGCGTTTCCAGCGTTTCCGCGTTTCGCGTTTCGCGTTTCAGCATAGTTAGCGTTTCATCGCGTTTCGCGTTTCTTTTATGCTGTTGCGTTTCTGCTTAGGCGTTTCTACACTCAGCGTTTCGCGTTTCAGCGTTTCAGCGTTTCACAGCGTTTCGCGTTTCTGGCGTTTCGCCGCGTTTCCCGTGCGTTTCATTCTTGCGTTTCTGCGTTTCTCGAGAGCGTTTCGCGTTTCGTACGCGTTTCGCGTTTCTTAAGAGCGTTTCCGCGTTTCGTTACGCGTTGCAAGCGTTTCGGCGTTTCTCAGGCGTTTCGTGCGTTTCTGCGTTTCGCGTTTCTTTGCGTTTCGCGTTTCGAAAGCGTTTCGGTTGCCTACGTATATACTTGCGTTTCGCGTTTCCTTCTAAAGGCGTTTCATAGCGTTTCGCCCTGGAGCGTTTCCGGAGAGCGTTTCTGCGTTTCAGCGTTTCTGCGTTTCAGGAGCGTTTCGGTGAGATTTAGCGTTTCCTATCGGCGTTTCTGGCGTTTCCTCGAAAGCGTTTCAGGCGTTTCATGCGTTTCTGCGTTTCGCGTTTCTCCGGCGTTTCGGCGTTTCGGCGTTTCGCGTTTCAGCGTTTCCAGCGTTTCAAGCGGCGTTTCACGCGTTTCGCGTTTCGCGTTTCGCGTTTCACTGCGTTTCAAGCGTTTCGCGTTTCGCGTTTCAACGCTGCGTTTCAGCGTTTCGCGTTTCGCGTTTCTGACCCGCGTTTCAGCGTTTCTGGGATAGCGTTTCGTGCGTTTCGCGTTTCGCGGTGACGCGTTTC
GCGTTTCGC
```

I get this error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

If you could help that would be great. I understand what the error is, and how I should fix it, but I don't know specifically what to fix in my code.

Comment: **Where** does the error occur? What is the *full* traceback of the exception?

Comment: And what if `first` is set to `len(large) - 1` (so the last available index in `large`)? You now try to add `other` to that, and for any value other than `0` for `other`, that'll give you an exception. The same will happen for any value starting at `len(large) - len(small)`, as you are guaranteed to generate values for `other` that'll exceed `len(large) - 1` when summing. What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: The error occurs on line 14: 'if small[other] == large[first + other]:'

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks, I think that fixed it. I'm trying to find out how many times "small" occurs in "large"

Comment: Like [Find all occurrences of a substring in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4664850) you mean?

Comment: Martijn likely solved your problem.  Just as a note- you shouldn't be going from 0 to len(large)... you should be going from 0 to (len(large)-len(small) ... this is the cause of your actual error.

Answer (score 0):

```
for first in range(0, len(large)):                       #1
    list = []
    if large[first] == small[0]:
        for other in range(0, len(small)):               #2
            if small[other] == large[first + other]:     #3
```

1. The largest value `first` will be is `len(large) - 1`.
2. The largest value `other` will be is `len(small) - 1`.
3. Thus, the largest value that `first + other` will be is `len(large) + len(small) - 2`.

Given that `len(small)` is 9 from your example input, `first + other` is clearly going to be larger than `len(large)` at some point, and yet you're trying to use it as an index for large.

You need to fix your logic - or, as [Martijn Pieters pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27209734/indexerror-list-index-out-of-range-error-python/27209786#comment42901238_27209734), use a simpler method.