# How to find number of times a string is repeating in particular string in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to find number of times a string present in a string in python

i already tried

```
my_str = "Hello world all in the world call me tell me"
sum(1 for x in my_str if x="ll")
```

i want its result as 4

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-python

Comment: How many `'ll'`s are there in `'Schalllampe'`?

Comment: @eumiro asked the right question: you could argue for an answer of 0 in his example (because there's no `ll` which isn't unambiguously separated), or 1 (because we don't allow overlaps), 2 (because we *do* allow overlaps), or even 3, though it's a stretch (because we allow you to skip internal duplicates in a group).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use string [count](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.count) method:

```
my_str.count('ll')
```