# Find and use multiple occurences of a string in a string

Tags: python, string, find

I recently started using Python and wrote some simple scripts
Now I have this question:

I have this string:

```
mystring = 'AAAABBAAABBAAAACCAAAACCAAAA'
```

and I have these following strings:

```
String_A = BB
String_B = CC
```

I would like to get all possible combinations of strings starting with String_A and ending with String_B (kind of vague so below is the desired output)

```
output: 
BBAAABBAAAACCAAACC
BBAAABBAAAACC
BBAAACCAAAACC
BBAAACC
```

I am able to count the number of occurences of String_A and String_B in mystring using

```
mystring.count()
```

And I am able to print out one specific output (the one with the first occurence of String_A and the first occurence of String_B), by doing the following:

```
if String_A in mystring:
    String_B_End = mystring.index(String_B) + len(String_B)
    output = mystring[mystring.index(String_A); String_B_End]
    print(output)
```

this works perfect but only gives me the following output:

```
BBAAABBAAAACC
```

How can I get all the specified output strings from mystring?
thanx in advance!

Comment: But your output is not *all possible combinations*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the intention of your question correctly you can use the following code:

```
>>> import re
>>> mystring = 'AAAABBAAABBAAAACCAAAACCAAAA'
>>> String_A = 'BB'
>>> String_B = 'CC'
>>> def find_occurrences(s, a, b):
        a_is = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(re.escape(a), s)] # All indexes of a in s
        b_is = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(re.escape(b), s)] # All indexes of b in s
        result = [s[i:j+len(b)] for i in a_is for j in b_is if j>i]
        return result
>>> find_occurrences(mystring, String_A, String_B)
['BBAAABBAAAACC', 'BBAAABBAAAACCAAAACC', 'BBAAAACC', 'BBAAAACCAAAACC']
```

This uses the find all occurrences of a substring code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4664889/637284)

In its current form the code does not work for overlapping substrings, if `mystring = 'BBB'` and you look for substring `'BB'` it only returns the index 0. If you want to account for such overlapping substrings change the lines where you are getting the indexes of the substrings to `a_is = [m.start() for m in re.finditer("(?={})".format(re.escape(a)), s)]`

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you need to get the indexes of `String_A` and `String_B` in the text. See this:

```
s = mystring
[i for i in range(len(s)-len(String_A)+1) if s[i:i+len(String_A)]==String_A]
```

it returns `[4, 9]`, i.e. the indexes of `'BB'` in `mystring`. You do similarly for String_B for which the answer would be `[15, 21]`.

Then you do this:

```
[(i, j) for i in [4, 9] for j in [15, 21] if i < j]
```

This line combines each starting location with each ending location and ensures that the starting location occurs before the ending location. The `i < j` would not be essential for this particular example, but in general you should have it. The result is `[(4, 15), (4, 21), (9, 15), (9, 21)]`.

Then you just convert the start and end indices to substrings:

```
[s[a:b+len(String_B)] for a, b in [(4, 15), (4, 21), (9, 15), (9, 21)]]
```