# Find a string in a string - Python

Tags: python, string

I am trying to implement a function that find a text in a string recursively.

I tried this, but I don't know why it's not working. Please note that I am new to coding.

```
def find(text, substring):
  if len(text) == 0:
     return 0
  while substring[0] in text:
     return find(text, substring[1:])
```

Thanks! :)

**Example**:

```
find("mississippi", "sip")
True
find("to be or not to be", "be")
True
find("mississippi", "sup")
False
```

Comment: What is the expected result, and what is the result you're getting?

Comment: You have a base case for when the end of the string is reached, but you also need a base case for when a match has been found.

Comment: @GregPrisament Do you mean "for when a match hasn't been found"?

Comment: Finding a substring fast isn't a completely trivial task, a recursive algorithm results in *O(n^2)* algorithm. Using the *Knuth-Patterson* algorithm, one can achieve *O(n)* linear time.

Answer (score 1):

There are much simpler ways to do this. For example, you can loop over the indices of the string and check if the substring is at that location, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4664915/4403123):

```
[i for i in range(len(string)) if s.startswith(substr,i)]
```

This will evaluate to a list of indices of all of the occurrences of `substr` in `string`.

Answer (score 0):

You need a base case for your recursive function that will eventually return without recursing. Your base case `len(text)==0` is never executed unless `text==''` the first time through.

Comment: There is a base case. If a function doesn't run a `return` statement, then it will return `None`.

Comment: @KSFT, yes. OP needs to clartify what desired result is; this function never returns True.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to implement a recursive function where `find(text, substring)`, given two strings, returns the same result as the simple Python expression `substring in text`.  A recursive breakdown of this problem would be:

- Does `text` begin with `substring`? If so, return `True`. (Base case 1)
- Is `text` empty?  If so, return `False`. (Base case 2).
- Otherwise, return the result of `find(text[1:], substring)` – the recursive case where we call the same function on a smaller problem.

See if you can implement that!  For base case one, you'll have good use of Python's String method `startswith` (google it!).