# replace wildcard numbers in pattern with additional text + same numbers

Tags: python, regex

I need to find all parts of a large text string in this particular pattern:

```
"\t\t" + number (between 1-999) + "\t\t"
```

and then replace each occurrence with:

```
TEXT+"\t\t"+same number+"\t\t"
```

So, the end result is:

> 'TEXT\t\t24\t\tblah blah blahTEXT\t\t56\t\t'... and so on...

The various numbers are between 1-999 so it needs some kind of wildcard.

Please can somebody show me how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Show us what you have tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find all occurrences of a substring in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use Python's `re` library, and in particular the `re.sub` function:

```
import re  # re is Python's regex library
SAMPLE_TEXT = "\t\t45\t\tbsadfd\t\t839\t\tds532\t\t0\t\t"  # Test text to run the regex on

# Run the regex using re.sub (for substitute)
# re.sub takes three arguments: the regex expression,
# a function to return the substituted text,
# and the text you're running the regex on.

# The regex looks for substrings of the form:
# Two tabs ("\t\t"), followed by one to three digits 0-9 ("[0-9]{1,3}"),
# followed by two more tabs.

# The lambda function takes in a match object x,
# and returns the full text of that object (x.group(0))
# with "TEXT" prepended.
output = re.sub("\t\t[0-9]{1,3}\t\t",
                lambda x: "TEXT" + x.group(0),
                SAMPLE_TEXT)

print output  # Print the resulting string.
```

Comment: Excellent! I don't know how it works - but it works! The part I don't understand is: lambda x: "TEXT" + x.group(0), is lambda part of the language? I need to research it but I don't know what "chapter" heading this comes under in a Python book... anyway, much thanks for a great answer!

Comment: I've added comments to the code, but a lambda function is part of Python. You can find the documentation for it [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda). It creates an anonymous function that takes in a variable x, and returns the value after the colon. Equivalently, I could have written:
`def foo(x):
    return "TEXT" + x.group(0)`, and used `foo` as the second argument of `re.sub`.

Comment: Thanks for commenting the solution - it's so elegant, a "one line" multipurpose text processing tool that you'd never find in any "cookbook" :-)  Thanks for sharing so generously. Much appreciated.