# Find all occurances of a substring with python separated by max distance

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to match all occurances of a substring with python.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-python), but I'd like to match occurances of a substring separated by at most some distance (for example maximum of 6). So if I have string

`AATCGTGCCGTGTGCCCCAAAATGAACGCGCCGCTGTG`

I want to get all positions of TG if two TG's are separated by at most 6 characters.
So in the example above I'd like to get `[5, 10, 12, 34, 36]`. I don't want the middle TG positions, because it is too far away from either "group" (for 10 characters).

I tried with this:

`(?=TG(?:.+){1,6}?)`

but it doesn't work.

*EDIT*

I created regex that returns all the positions I want, except the last ones.

```
(?=TG.{0,6}TG)
```

If I use example above, returned positions are marked with `|`

```
AATCG|TGCCG|TGTGCCCCAAAATGAACGCGCCGC|TGTG
```

but I'd like to get also positions marked with `\`

```
AATCG|TGCCG|TG\TGCCCCAAAATGAACGCGCCGC|TG\TG
```

I know why it doesn't work, because it matches all TG followed by 0-6 random characters and one more TG, but I cannot get the idea what should I add to make it work.

Comment: Please correct your description or example.... 10 - 5 < 6

Comment: " if distance between two TG's are maximum 6" - please clarify. Again, your example contradicts the description.

Comment: `str.find` is possible, but I'd like to do it with regex.

Comment: _Why_ do you want to do this with regex?

Comment: I want to get positions of TG separated by at most _some distance_. For example 6. So I want first three TGs in the final list, because they are separated for less than 6 characters (in first example they are 5 characters away and in second they are 2). At the end TGs are also separated by 2 characters.

Comment: @JoshCaswell to do it with one line. I don't know how to do it with one line if using `str.find`.

Comment: Why do you need to do it in one line?

Answer (score 1):

If using a regex, I think this should work.
The position has to be obtained from the position of capture group 1.

*Note - I think your position `34` is not valid.*

`(?:^.*?|(?<=TG).{0,4})(TG)`

**Edit:**

You can also do it this way to get the start of a new group of TG's.

**Using `\K`** - no capture groups: `(?:(?<=TG).{0,4}\KTG|.*?\KTG(?=.{0,4}TG))`
Formatted:

```
 (?:
      (?<= TG )
      .{0,4} 
      \K 
      TG
   |  
      .*? 
      \K 
      TG
      (?= .{0,4} TG )
 )
```

**Without *Branch Reset*** - 2 capture groups:  `(?:(?<=TG).{0,4}(TG)|.*?(TG)(?=.{0,4}TG))`
Formatted:

```
 (?:
      (?<= TG )
      .{0,4} 
      ( TG )                        # (1)
   |  
      .*? 
      ( TG )                        # (2)
      (?= .{0,4} TG )
 )
```

**With *Branch Reset*** - 1 capture group:  `(?|(?<=TG).{0,4}(TG)|.*?(TG)(?=.{0,4}TG))`

Formatted:

```
 (?|
      (?<= TG )
      .{0,4} 
      ( TG )                        # (1)
   |  
      .*? 
      ( TG )                        # (1)
      (?= .{0,4} TG )
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, where you first find all the occurences, and then check the distance between indexes afterwards:

```
text = AATCGTGCCGTGTGCCCCAAAATGAACGCGCCGCTGTG
positions = []
index = 0

# Get all positions
while index < len(text):
    index = text.find('TG', index)
    positions.append(index)
    index += 2 # +2 because len('TG') == 2

# Filter out positions where distance are maximum 6
for i in range(1,len(positions)):
    if(((positions[i] - positions[i-1]) > 6) and ((positions[i+1] - positions[i]) > 6)): # check distance in both directions
        del positions[i]

# print resulting list
print positions
```

I haven't checked it, but it should do the job.