# Replacing Substrings Under Certain Conditions

Tags: python

Here is what I have:

```
stem_text = "x^3+21x^2+1x+6"
```

And I would like to change it to:

```
stem_text = "x^3+21x^2+x+6"
```

Here's what my code looks like:

```
indices = [m.start() for m in re.finditer("1x", stem_text)]
for i in indices:
    if stem_text[i-1] not in ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]:
        stem_text = stem_text.replace(stem_text[i:i+2],"x")`
```

But, it is replacing both occurrences of "1x" still.

I have used these two posts to get me to a point where I think what I have should be working, but it is not:

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148120/python-3-replace-in-strings
- [Find all occurrences of a substring in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-python)

Comment: Are you looking only to replace exact occurrences of `1x`?

Comment: you could try changing the regular expression to '\+1x' rather than just '1x'

Comment: A simple regex would be really easy here. replace /(\D)1x/ with $1x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are looking to replace all exact occurrences of `1x` with `x`, you  can use `re.sub`

```
import re

stem_text = "x^3+21x^2+1x+6"

re.sub(r'\b1x\b', 'x', stem_text)
```

`\b` here means [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

Answer (score 1):

If equation has only addition operator:

```
stem_text = "x^3+21x^2+1x+6"

new_string = stem_text.replace('+1x','+x')
print(new_string)
```

Output:

```
x^3+21x^2+x+6
```

If equation has multiple operators:

```
stem_text = '1x+1x-1x/1x*1x+10x'
op_list = ['','+','-','*','/']
#list of operations in equation
for each_op in op_list:
    stem_text = stem_text.replace(each_op+'1x',each_op+'x') #'each_op + 1x' is used to prevent replacing nos. like 21x,31x etc


print(stem_text)
```

Output:

```
x+x-x/x*x+10x
```

Note: This is inefficient solution

Answer (score 0):

add \b to your pattern `1x` for exact match the word 1x other than matching `21x` or other words contain `1x`

```
import re
stem_text = "x^3+21x^2+1x+6"

print(re.sub(r'\b1x\b', r'x', stem_text))
```

The result is

```
x^3+21x^2+x+6
```

Read python regex [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to replace just "1x" use this example :

```
stem_text = "x^3+21x^2+1x+6"
indices = [x for x in stem_text.split("+")]
for i in indices:
    if len(i) == 2 and i == "1x": stem_text = stem_text.replace(i + "+", "x+")

print stem_text
```

output : `x^3+21x^2+x+6`

else if you want to replace any number before "x" use this example :

```
stem_text = "x^3+21x^2+1x+6+2x+4x+0x"
indices = [x for x in stem_text.split("+")]
Int = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"]
for x in indices:
    for i in Int:
        if x == i + "x": stem_text = stem_text.replace(i + "x", "x")

print stem_text
```

output : `x^3+x^2+x+6+x+x+x`

Comment: Your first example replaces the `1x` in `21x` which isn't what OP wants I believe. The idea behind replacing `1x` with `x` is because in math, the "1" in front of the "x" is called an "implied 1" and, so it's simply written as x.

Comment: @ILostMySpoon ohh, I miss it. thanks I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers before already do the job. This is a solution, inspired in another answer to this question, but, it can be used with any letter in your string. As described in [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub), it's called backreferences

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = r'\b1(\w)\b'
>>> print(re.sub(regex, r'\g<1>', 'z^3+4z^2+1z+5'))
z^3+4z^2+z+5
>>> print(re.sub(regex, r'\g<1>', 'y^3+21y^2+1y+6'))
y^3+21y^2+y+6
```