# Regex execution time analysis

Tags: regex, performance, execution-time

Some of regular expression have exponential time of execution due to bad syntax and non-obvious details. Is there any common way to analyze and learn if some regular expression have linear or exponential execution time?

Comment: apparently [Regex is evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-python#comment83882449_4664850)

Comment: @uhoh, yes - now I know it for sure

Comment: Thanks for the warning, I'm going to avoid it for now. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I tend to just use `perl` and switch on `use re 'debug';` before doing a regex operation.

This prints the steps the regex is going through to process, and quickly gives an idea of efficiency.

There's no hard and fast rules - the big warning sign I look for is whether this regex will need to backtrack. See: [Catastrophic Backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)

This can happen *more* easily when you're using lookahead/lookbehind (but doesn't have to).

In the grand scheme of things though - it pays to remember that whilst regex is a  programming language, it's *starting* point is as a power search-and-replace. And thus implementing complicated logic in it, means you're creating code that's hard to maintain and debug - and so you shouldn't.

One of the useful tricks in perl - it can run in much the same way as `sed`/`grep`/`awk` using command line.

So you can enable regex debugging, and then do 'sed style':

```
perl -pe 's/search/replace' somefile
```

But then you can add 'debug' regex:

```
perl -Mre=debug -pe 's/search/replace/' somefile
```

Which will debug it whilst you're going.

Comment: Catastrophic backtracking is the most serious offender - beware of nested quantifiers.

Comment: I think I just discovered a reason to use Perl :)