# How do I find quotes in strings - Python

Tags: python, string, indexing, quotes

Let's say I have a String variable

```
temp = 'I need to "leave" this place'
```

How would I be able to use temp.index() to find where the quotes("") begin and end?

Comment: `temp.index('"')`, or `temp.index("\"")`.

Comment: You can also use `\` as an escape: `temp.index('\"')`

Comment: or use regex `".*?"` :D

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-python

Answer (score 3):

Note: As said in the other answer, I would advise you to use the `find(substring)` function. To my knowledge both `index` and `find` work equally well, but if you use `index(substring)`, you will have to handle the possible `ValueError` exception if `substring` is not found.

So to find where the quotes begin and end, you would do the following:

First, find where the first quote is (i.e. where the quotes begin):

```
    startIndex = temp.find('\"')
```

Now we need to know if the string even had any quote to begin with. The `find(substring)` function will return `-1` if `substring` is not found. If `substring` was found, then let's find the index of the second quote. If that second quote is found, then lets print out the start and end indices of the quotes.

```
    if startIndex != -1: #i.e. if the first quote was found
        endIndex = temp.find('\"', startIndex + 1)
        if startIndex != -1 and endIndex != -1: #i.e. both quotes were found
            print 'Start: ' + str(startIndex)
            print 'End: ' + str(endIndex)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [find](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_find.htm) method.

```
start_pt = temp.find("\"")
end_pt = temp.find("\"", start_pt + 1)  # add one to skip the opening "
quote = temp[start_pt + 1: end_pt]

>>> print start_pt, end_pt, quote
10, 16, 'leave'
```