# Faster way to print all starting indices of a substring in a string, including overlapping occurences

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-matching

I'm trying to answer this homework question: Find all occurrences of a pattern in a string. Different occurrences of a substring can overlap with each other.

> Sample 1.
>
> Input:
>
> TACG
>
> GT
>
> Output:
>
> Explanation: The pattern is longer than the text and hence has no occurrences in the text.
>
> Sample 2.
>
> Input:
>
> ATA
>
> ATATA
>
> Output:
>
> 0 2
>
> Explanation: The pattern appears at positions 1 and 3 (and these two occurrences overlap each other).
>
> Sample 3.
>
> ATAT
>
> GATATATGCATATACTT
>
> Output:
>
> 1 3 9
>
> Explanation: The pattern appears at positions 1, 3, and 9 in the text.

The answer I'm submitting is this one:

```
def all_indices(text, pattern):
    i = text.find(pattern)
    while i >= 0:
        print(i, end=' ')
        i = text.find(pattern, i + 1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    text = input()
    pattern = input()
    all_indices(text, pattern)
```

However, this code is failing the final test cases:

> Failed case #63/64: time limit exceeded (Time used: 7.98/4.00, memory used: 77647872/536870912.)

The online judge knows I'm sending the answer in Python, and has different time limits for different languages.

I have searched quite a bit for other answers and approaches: [regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-python), [suffix trees](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ptrus/suffix-trees/master/suffix_trees/STree.py), [Aho-Corasick](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/atdt/875e0dba6a15e3fa6018/raw/48cffa784dfb0aeedec0be3a16cc3444c77c3762/aho_corasick.py)... but so far all of them underperform this simple solution (maybe because `find` is [implemented in C](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/stringlib/find.h)?).

So my question is: are there ways to do this task faster?

Comment: @Barmar in which case? I just tried the second most voted answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1 , and the result is the same.

Comment: I'm not sure. The bug doesn't seem obvious to me. If you run it yourself, does it eventually finish? How long does it take?

Comment: @Barmar unfortunately, they don't provide us the test cases :(

Comment: Any algorithm that does this will take time proportional to the length of the text. So they can always make a text long enough to exceed some time limit.

Comment: Have they told you the maximum possible lengths of the strings?

Comment: @Barmar Yes. It's `10e6` for both text and pattern.

Comment: The worst case would be something like `pattern = 'A'`, `text = 'A' * 10e6`

Comment: @Barmar thank you. It terminates! For the case you gave, just took a lot longer than 4 seconds to print all the string indices :D. Still wondering if there is a faster way...

Comment: One optimization is to stop when `i > len(text) - len(pattern)`

Comment: @Barmar I'm now thinking that the `print` calls are slowing down my answer...

Comment: I assume you're required to print the indexes, so there's nothing you can do to avoid that cost.

Comment: @Barmar true. The time is still the same with the optimization you mentioned, probably because the test case is the one you gave me before. I'll try implementing different algorithms to see if the test cases are more lenient towards a specific one.

Comment: That optimization will help with a case like `text = really long string`, `pattern = almost as long string that only appears once`

Answer (score 1):

If `print` is what slows your program the most, you should try to call it as little as possible. A quick and dirty solution to your problem:

```
def all_indices(string, pattern):
    result = []
    idx = string.find(pattern)
    while idx >= 0:
        result.append(str(idx))
        idx = string.find(pattern, idx + 1)
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    string = input()
    pattern = input()
    ' '.join(all_indices(string, pattern))
```

In the future to correctly identify which part of your code is slowing down the whole process you can use the [python profilers](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/profile.html)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the test cases were being more lenient towards the [Knuth-Morris-Pratt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) algorithm. This code, copied from https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/String_searching/Knuth-Morris-Pratt_pattern_matcher#Python, passed all the cases:

```
# Knuth-Morris-Pratt string matching
# David Eppstein, UC Irvine, 1 Mar 2002

#from http://code.activestate.com/recipes/117214/
def KnuthMorrisPratt(text, pattern):

    '''Yields all starting positions of copies of the pattern in the text.
    Calling conventions are similar to string.find, but its arguments can be
    lists or iterators, not just strings, it returns all matches, not just
    the first one, and it does not need the whole text in memory at once.
    Whenever it yields, it will have read the text exactly up to and including
    the match that caused the yield.'''

    # allow indexing into pattern and protect against change during yield
    pattern = list(pattern)

    # build table of shift amounts
    shifts = [1] * (len(pattern) + 1)
    shift = 1
    for pos in range(len(pattern)):
        while shift <= pos and pattern[pos] != pattern[pos-shift]:
            shift += shifts[pos-shift]
        shifts[pos+1] = shift

    # do the actual search
    startPos = 0
    matchLen = 0
    for c in text:
        while matchLen == len(pattern) or \
              matchLen >= 0 and pattern[matchLen] != c:
            startPos += shifts[matchLen]
            matchLen -= shifts[matchLen]
        matchLen += 1
        if matchLen == len(pattern):
            yield startPos
```