# Python count "4" in an int

Tags: python-3.x, count

how could i count the 4 in an integer with python.

The integer is 3 to the 10000.
And I would like to know how often is the 4 in this integer.

maybe something like:
count 4 in 3**10000

Comment: You should show the value and type you have and what result you want, this is very unclear as it stands.

Comment: 1) calculate the value and save as a string.  2) get count of "4" in string.

Comment: yes but can I do that in Python ?

Comment: Convert each integer to a string using `str(...)`, then use the suggestions of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4664850/3082472) to find all occurrences of the string `'4'`. Also, as you're new here, I'd like to  recommend reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Cheers!

Comment: Are you asking us to do your homework?

Answer (score 1):

The following works:

```
len(str(3**10000).split('4'))-1
```

or as suggested below:

```
str(3**10000).count('4')
```

both give 495.

Comment: this is like counting male population in a city by counting how many houses have a family with a husband/dad, its correct but kinda inefficient

Comment: You know `str.count` also exist