# Python Find Word in Text

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am writing a Python Program where I can get the location of the word in a paragraph and the number of times the word has appeared in the paragraph included in the program. Currently, my code only outputs 2 locations of a word entered.

```
text = '''This is sample text to test if this pythonic program can 
serve as
an indexing platform for finding words in a paragraph. It can give 
values
as to where the word is located with the different examples as 
stated'''

find_str = input("Please Enter Word to Search: ")
x = 0
i = text.find(find_str, x)
print (i)
i = text.find(find_str, i+1)
print (i)
```

If I enter "as", this is the output:

```
Please Enter Word to Search: as
63
140
>>>
```

How do I make the code output all of the locations of the entered word, and additionally the number of times the word has appeared in the paragraph?

Comment: This should be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-python

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop

Comment: https://www.dotnetperls.com/find-python

Comment: The code is here https://onlinegdb.com/HJDVx2hGX

Comment: Ok, but how do I make the code count the number of times the word has appeared?