# Find space in a line in a file

Tags: python

I am reading a file line by line. I use a function to find specified characters in a line.

```py
def find_all(a_str, sub):
    start = 0
    while True:
        start = a_str.find(sub, start)
        if start == -1: return
        yield start
        start += len(sub)

with open("file.txt", 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:                                                              
        a = list(find_all(line,"==")
```

This works fine, it will find "==" but I actually need this to find spaces which are somehow omitted when I use:

```
a = list(find_all(line," "))
```

What change do I need to make to find spaces?

Comment: Could you provide an example of an input and the expected result?

Comment: Please indent your code correctly

Comment: One thing you'll need to change is add a `)` at the end of your last line.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand, this works perfectly :

```
list(find_all('This works perfectly doesn t it ?'," "))
[4, 10, 20, 26, 28, 31]
```

Could you provide your sample data ? Maybe your spaces are special characters ?

Also, I suppose you saw this, but just in case : [Find all occurrences of a substring in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-python)

Comment: Yes this actually works, not sure why it's not working in my other code. 

And yes, the link you provided is where I borrowed it from.

Answer (score 0):

As @Hoog stated above, you are missing a parentheses at the end of your code.

```
def find_all(a_str, sub):
    start = 0
    while True:
        start = a_str.find(sub, start)
        if start == -1: return
        yield start
        start += len(sub)

with open("file.txt", 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:                                                              
        a = list(find_all(line,"==")) # << Right here
```

Comment: It was a typo, I've added it. Unfortunately adding it has no effect on the result