# find all substring in a string without iterating

Tags: python, string, iteration, substring

given a long string, for example: `str = 'abbabaab'`

and a short substring: `sub = 'ab'`.

I want to get a list of all the indexes where the substring can be found, ***without*** iterating over the string.

the expected result would be: `res = [0, 3, 6]`

Comment: "_**without**_ iterating over the string" - Why?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4664889/3129414) solve your problem?

Comment: @arsho `.finditer` is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Coming from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-python/4664889#4664889):

```
import re

str = 'abbabaab'
sub = 'ab'

res = [x.start() for x in re.finditer(sub, str)]
print(res)                                            # [0, 3, 6]
```