# Hangman game project

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to a hangman game. I already achieved to set the basics of the game (list, interaction with user) but I don't know how to do the lines for the game, keep asking and printing what the user correct answers are and ilustrate the hangman.
I used index in order to search the exact location of the letter in the word, but I dont know to print it, depending on the number and also I don't how to code that the program keeps track of the correct words.

I would be totally glad for your help. Also thanks for your patience.
The first part of the code is well coded but stackoverflow doesn't display it right.

## ------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
import random
def hangman():
    words = ['house','car','women', 'university','mother', 'school', 'computer','pants']   #list of words
    computer  = words[random.randint(0,6)]  #computerchoice
    word = list(computer)  #Make a list with each letter of the word. 

    welcome = (input ('Welcome, type ok to continue: '))
    if welcome == 'ok':
        length = len(word)
        print(f'help? the word has {length} letters')
        option = (input('Start guessing, letter by letter'))
        count= 0   #count takes the count of how many tries. 
        chances = length+3   #You are able to make 3 mistakes. 
        while count<=chances:
        
            if option in word:    #if the choice is there
                place = word.index(option)  #search for the place. 
                print()   #dont know how to print it in 'that' place. 
                #place the correct letter over that line.
                print('_ '*length)  #Trying to do the  under  lines. 
                count+=1
    else:
        break 
#Dont know to ilustrate the hangman depending on the length of the word. 


hangman()
```

Comment: Edit your question, Highlight your code and press the `{}` button.  It will be formatted nicely

Comment: @Hoog `{}` is 2 buttons? Or highlight all the code and hit `ctrl+k`

Comment: @MattB it appears to me as only 1 button but the shortcut `CTRL+K` is an even better idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First let's analyse your code:

```
import random
def hangman():
    words = ['house','car','women', 'university','mother', 'school','computer','pants']   #list of words
    computer  = words[random.randint(0,6)]  #computerchoice
    word = list(computer)  #Make a list with each letter of the word.
```

Everything is fine up to here , although str can be used the same way as a list , so no need to transform it.

```
    welcome = (input ('Welcome, type ok to continue: '))
    if welcome == 'ok':
        length = len(word)
        print(f'help? the word has {length} letters')
```

Yes but those are not unique letters. You can use set() to have the number of unique letters.

```
        option = (input('Start guessing, letter by letter'))
```

If your input starts here, you will only ask once for a letter , you need to include this part in the while loop

```
        count= 0   #count takes the count of how many tries. 
        chances = length+3   #You are able to make 3 mistakes.
```

This would then probably be changed to the length of the set.

```
        while count<=chances:

            if option in word:    #if the choice is there
                place = word.index(option)  #search for the place.
```

This will only give you the index of the first occurence.
We should keep in mind to use regex for this type of search : [Find all occurrences of a substring in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-python)

```
                print()   #dont know how to print it in 'that' place.
```

Let's remember to use the print formating `f'stufff{value}stuffff'`

```
                #place the correct letter over that line.
```

To do it , you need to create a str only with `_`and then fill it in with the indexes using list comprehension .

```
                print('_ '*length)  #Trying to do the  under  lines. 
                count+=1
```

Maybe we should handle what happens if option is not in words ?

```
    else:
        break 
    #Dont know to ilustrate the hangman depending on the length of the word.
```

Also there is no need for break : count increments and therefore while will terminate. And if it was for the outer if/else , break doesn't work outside a loop.

```
hangman()
```

## Question for OP:

What point would you like to sort out yourself ? What do you need help for next ?

Comment: This is how help should be offered to new learners, props to you for the very informative and helpful answer +1