# Can we find 2nd occurence index of a particular character in a string in python

Tags: python-3.x, indexof

Consider I Want to find 2nd occurence of char 'o' in string 'Hello World'(we can see the index would be 7). Can we write using 'index' or 'find' method in python?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it on several ways, here are some of them:

```
def find_all(a_str, sub):
    start = 0
    while True:
        start = a_str.find(sub, start)
        if start == -1: return
        yield start
        start += len(sub) # use start += 1 to find overlapping matches

string =  'Hello World'
print (list(find_all(string, 'o'))[1])
```

output:

7

```
string =  'Hello World'
print([i for i in range(len(string)) if string.startswith('o', i)][1])
```

output:

7

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex, which also works for substrings, as seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4664889/11335072):

```
import re
indexes = [m.start() for m in re.finditer('o', 'Hello World')]  # [4, 7]
print(indexes[1])  # get second occurrence
```