# Problem with Python Task that contains variable count

Tags: python

CAN YOU HELP ME WITH THIS PYTHON TASK====1.based on the variable: str1="one two three twenty one thirty one fifty one" and the help of one or more string management methods, you are asked to check if it contains more than twice the string 'one'. If yes, then the program should say "More than Two". IF not , then the program should say "There are fewer than two"

Comment: If you have a specific question post the relevant code and ask the question, if you are just looking for someone to do it for you you are in the wrong place.

Comment: So... What's the problem? SO is not a code-writing service, we can only help you with concrete problems when you show us your code. If you need a hint: think how would you do this on paper. There are more possible solutions to this, but this is the simplest thing you can code.

Comment: First you should try to solve it, and provide the code you are trying.

Comment: I ll use the variable : string1.count("one")  but I don t know which variable should I choose to check if There are MORE than two "one" ..I know all the other task. Only that is confusing me .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
str1="one two three twenty thirty fifty one"
if str1.count("one") > 2:
    print("More than Two")
else:
    print("There are fewer than two")
```

Comment: Thank you Vaibhav Jadhav..It was simple and I was confused. You' re great!!

Comment: @ΠαναγιώτηςΦασουλίδης Welcome. Try it and you will get it step by step. :-)

Comment: Yeah, of course