# python search file hex value and list keyword offset

Tags: python, search, hex, findall

In Python, I am trying to get the offset (relative to the beginning of the file) of byte-code `0x8212` on a binary file with the following code

```
with open('test.bin', 'rb') as f:
    s = f.read()
    k = s.find(b'\x82\x12')
    for l in k:
        print(l)
```

but it throws error

```
TypeError:'int' object in not interable.
```

Please advice.

Comment: error means that `k` holds integer and you con't iterate over it.

Answer (score 1):

`string.find()` returns the lowest index occurence of the value, Therefore `k`  is an integer and not a list and cannot be iterated over.

If you want a list try using regex or reference this article: [How to find all occurrences of a substring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring)