# Guessing letters in a word in python

Tags: python

I'm a beginner at python and I was trying to write a program to guess the letters in a word, (here I used 'coconut' ). There is no limitation for guesses. If the guess was correct each time, I want to display the position of the letter as another ( 'guess_map').

So I defined the list `guess_map` with same length of the word. Then using for loop I was checking the guessed input with the word and replacing the corresponding element in the list 'guess_map'.

But then I found its not working for the letters which are repeating. For example 'c'. The code is just considering the first 'c' in the word. I don't know where I have committed mistake. Can anyone help?

```
word = 'coconut'
reference = list(word)
number_letters = len(reference)
guess_map = ['-']*number_letters

guess = input('Guess the letter')
for let in reference:
    if let == guess:
        ref_ind = reference.index(let)
        guess_map[ref_ind] = guess

print(guess_map)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find all occurrences of a substring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring)

Answer (score 2):

The mistake is in `ref_ind = reference.index(let)`. This will only ever find the first occurrence, even though the loop finds all of them.

This version of your program uses `enumerate` to give you the right index every time.

```
word = 'coconut'
reference = list(word)
final = reference[:]
number_letters = len(reference)
guess_map = ['-']*number_letters


while guess_map != final:
    guess = input('Guess the letter')
    for ref_ind, let in enumerate(reference):
        if let == guess:
            guess_map[ref_ind] = guess

    print(guess_map)

print("Done")
```

I've taken the liberty of adding a loop which keeps you guessing until you get it right.

Comment: While this wasn't a stipulation from the OP, guesses that are the correct letter, but different case will not be accepted. You can change this behavior by using `str.casefold` in your comparisons, and appending `let` instead of `guess` to `guess_map`.

Comment: Yes, I have also tried: `guess = input('Guess the letter').lower()`

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it. But i didn't understand 'while guess_map != final:' this line.

Comment: Sorry, `final` is not a keyword. I added `final = reference[:]` to easily check when the user had finished.

Comment: yeah i got it. You defined 'final' above. Thanks !