# re.error: unterminated character set at position while reading stirng

Tags: python, list, error-handling, python-re

This is string that I got

This given stirng

`Immunodeficiency with increased immunoglobulin [M] [IgM]`
`Maternal care for anti-D [Rh] antibodies, unspecified trimester`

I tried to finding multiple occurrences of a string within a string in Python, and get their index.

so, 
with a input string

```
  char = random input string
```

I wanted result like this:

```
result = [[index, index, index],[index, index, index ]]
```

so, this is code that I used.

```
            a = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(char,given string)]
```

,but it didn't work for metacharacters, and caused re.error: unterminated character set at position 0

how can I improve this code?

Comment: What is `char` here?

Comment: Char is a Random input string such as meta-character, alphabet, or number

Comment: The first argument to `re.finditer()` is supposed to be a regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `re.finditer()` with a random input string, you need to escape it in case it contains characters that have special meaning in regular expressions.

```
regex = re.escape(char)
a = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(regex,given string)]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solved my problem, but I used re.finditer(), because that's the only think that learned. Is there any better function for finding occurrences of a string?

Comment: Apparently not. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring