# How to find multiple substrings in a string and add them to a list?

Tags: python

Im trying to add every substring that occurs in my list, so in the word "hello" it would return [2,3] as the index values found in the string. I don't know how to have it re-iterate after every substring is found.

```
def myFind(string,substring):

    if (string.find(substring) == -1):
        return []

    i = 0
    list = []
    while i < len(string):
        x = string.find(substring)
        list.append(x)
        i +=1
    return list
print (myFind("Hello","l"))
```

Comment: [`str.find()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) as an extra optional argument `start`... So just pass `i` to find: `string.find(substring, i)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find all occurrences of a substring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring) @A-y you are right. Why didn't you flag it?

Comment: Just figured out how to flag :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the module, [re](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwij__CK8OjpAhWOmuAKHbmiC7wQFjAAegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.python.org%2F3%2Flibrary%2Fre.html&usg=AOvVaw3Rsq9kABRxR4gH08n-cRdW):

```
import re

s = 'hello'

print([i.start() for i in re.finditer('l', s)])
```

Output:

```
[2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could do it with a list comprehension:

```
def my_find(s,sub):
    "get all indices of substring sub in string s"
    return [i for i in range(0,len(s)-len(sub)+1) if s[i:i+len(sub)] == sub]
```