# Want to find the positions where a pattern (substring) starts in another string in python

Tags: python, rosalind

Input:

```
strA = "ATATATGCGATAT"
strB = "ATAT"
```

output:

```
0 2 9
```

I was looking for a way to find the starting positions in a string (strA), every time a pattern (strB) starts.

Comment: You can use kmp algorithm for this.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring