# Find the matching opening/closing brace index in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want the index of the corresponding brace in a for loop of a string like this for example: `"(foo(bar))"`.

At first I did it like this, but it would always match the right/leftmost brace and thus it would not work with multiple braces:

```
for item in string:
    if item == "(":
        matchingbraceindex = string.find(")", item)

    elif item == ")":
        matchingbraceindex = string.rfind("(", 0, item)
```

Then I thought about counting the braces but I still wouldn't get the index, just the position among other braces, which I couldn't think of a way to extract an index from.

Comment: What output are you expecting for input `(foo(bar))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a stack, keep track of all of the pairs as you traverse the string:

```
def find_matching_parens(s, braces=None):
    openers = braces or {"(": ")"}
    closers = {v: k for k, v in openers.items()}
    stack = []
    result = []

    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        if c in openers:
            stack.append([c, i])
        elif c in closers:
            if not stack:
                raise ValueError(f"tried to close brace without an open at position {i}")

            pair, idx = stack.pop()
            result.append([idx, i])

            if pair != closers[c]:
                raise ValueError(f"mismatched brace at position {i}")
    
    if stack:
        raise ValueError(f"no closing brace at position {i}")

    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(find_matching_parens("(foo(bar)()baz(a(fz()asdf)))"))
```

Output:

```
[[4, 8], [9, 10], [19, 20], [16, 25], [14, 26], [0, 27]]
```

If you just want the matching bracket for a specific index, you can use this modification to the above function:

```
def find_matching_paren(s, i, braces=None):
    openers = braces or {"(": ")"}
    closers = {v: k for k, v in openers.items()}
    stack = []
    result = []

    if s[i] not in openers:
        raise ValueError(f"char at index {i} was not an opening brace")

    for ii in range(i, len(s)):
        c = s[ii]

        if c in openers:
            stack.append([c, ii])
        elif c in closers:
            if not stack:
                raise ValueError(f"tried to close brace without an open at position {i}")

            pair, idx = stack.pop()

            if pair != closers[c]:
                raise ValueError(f"mismatched brace at position {i}")

            if idx == i:
                return ii
    
    if stack:
        raise ValueError(f"no closing brace at position {i}")

    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(find_matching_paren("(foo(barbaz(a(fz()asdf))))", 4)) # => 24
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a stack. Push left parens until you come across a right paren, at which time you’ve found the innermost pair. It’s not clear from your question what output you’re looking for, so I can’t say what to do with the letters.

Answer (score 0):

```
indexes_of_opening_brackets = []
indexes_of_closing_brackets = []

for index, item in enumerate(string):
    if item == "(":
        indexes_of_opening_brackets.append(index)
    elif item == ")":
        indexes_of_closing_brackets.append(index)
```

I didn't try the code, but I think it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, If I understand your question correctly, this is what you want.
Here I am appending the values in a dictionary after searching "(" and ")" in the string

```
string = "(foo(bar))"

print(string.find(")"))
num = string.count(")")
a = 0
b = 0
dict_ = {"open": [], "close": []}
a = string.find("(", a)
dict_["open"].append(a)

for _ in range(0, num):
    a = string.find("(", a+1)
    dict_["open"].append(a)
    b = string.find(")", b+1)
    dict_["close"].append(b)

dict_["open"].pop(-1)
print(dict_)
```

Answer (score 0):

Stack is the easiest way to solve the problem. The below solution will give you the start and end index of every pair of braces as a list of tuples.

In [37]: string = '(foo(bar))'

```
In [38]: braces_stack = []
    ...:
    ...: pairs = []
    ...:
    ...: for index, char in enumerate(string):
    ...:     if char=='(':
    ...:         braces_stack.append(index)
    ...:     elif char==')':
    ...:         idx = braces_stack.pop()
    ...:         pairs.append((idx, index))
    ...:
    ...:

In [39]: pairs
Out[39]: [(4, 8), (0, 9)]
```

Answer (score -2):

Use a regular expression ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring))

```
import re
[m.start() for m in re.finditer('\(', '(foo(bar))')]

[0, 4]
```