# Python program to Print out the number of times the pattern of a provided Substring matches in a provided String

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I have tried to frame a program in **Python** which would print out the **number of times** the provided **substring** appears as a pattern in a provided **string**.

Unfortunately, my code isn't the best solution as it might not handle some corner cases. I need a solution two-liner or three-liner code maybe) or a modified version to my code.

I also need some suggestions on code optimization if the provided input string is of length 1000 or more.

*Input 1*:

"**XYZ**DF**XYZ**XY"

**"XYZ"**

*Output 1*:

2

*Input 2*:

"AB**CDCDC**"

"**CDC**"

*Output 2*:

2

*My code*:

```
def pattern(string, sub_str ):
    counter = 0
    len_sub = len(sub_str )
    string, sub_str = string.upper(),sub_str.upper()
    for i in range(len(string)):
        sub_loop = ""
        for j in range(i,i+len_sub):
            try:
                sub_loop+=string[j] 
                if sub_loop == sub_str:
                    counter+=1
            except:
                pass
    return counter

if __name__ == '__main__':
    string = input().strip()
    sub_str = input().strip()
    count= pattern(string, sub_str )
    print(count)
```

Comment: `print("XYZDFXYZXY".count("XYZ"))` ?

Comment: Hi @PatrickArtner. I have mentioned "pattern" in my question. Let's say in a Test case, given input String is "ABCDCDC" and the given input Substring is "CDC".
According to your solution which is basically searching for a String not pattern, the output will be 1 but actually the ground value count of "CDC" is 2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find all occurrences of a substring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring)

Comment: @Ricky_Rick if you want to do this with somewhat short code, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34445090/6508598). If you want it to be fast (O(n) instead of O(n^2)), check out [KMP-algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm). It's relatively easy to understand and there are probably implementations already written in python.

Comment: @shananton Thank you. This satisfies my demand more than enough. I am also able to find the occurrence of a sub-string.

Answer (score 3):

#### For overlapping patterns:

For overlapping cases we will use regex's Positive Lookahead `(?=)`:

```
sub_str = "CDC"
string = "ABCDCDC"
len(re.findall(f"(?=({sub_str}))", string))
```

more info can be found here: https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

#### Without overlapping:

Python's `str` has a builtin function `count` that let you count the number of substring occurrences in the original string.

From the function documentation:

```
S.count(sub[, start[, end]]) -> int

Return the number of non-overlapping occurrences of substring sub in
string S[start:end].  Optional arguments start and end are
interpreted as in slice notation.
```

So eventually, all you have to do is:

`"XYZDFXYZXY".count("XYZ")`

so in total:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    string = input().strip()
    sub_str = input().strip()
    count = string.count(sub_str)
    print(count)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @OrY `"ABABA".count("ABA")` gives 1, while the OP's desired output seems to be 2

Comment: @shananton I've edited my answer to support both overlapping and non overlapping cases.

Comment: @OrY Thank you for the update on solving the problem with RegExp. I didn't really want to touch RegExp at all while solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution is to use the split() and then get the length of the resulting array minus 1. In your code above:

```py
def pattern(string, sub_str ):

    string, sub_str = string.upper(),sub_str.upper()
    Outarray= string.split(sub_str)
    counter = len(outarry) - 1
    Return counter
```

Answer (score 0):

Using *List Comprehension* reduced the whole code to one line.

```
def pattern(string, sub_str):
    counter = sum([1 for i in range(len(string)) if string[i:].startswith(sub_str)])
    return counter
```