# To identify repeated words and get the distance between two words as a list in python

Tags: python

```
A = "AEJXKWKJSSSJKZJLJLEJSSLKXMPPLSSKKDNEMSMLDMMEPPLETFMM"
print Repeat_Letter : [PPL:16, JSS:10]   --> What I want
```

String A is a string that lists random characters that I suggested. Some of them are repetitive string. Repeated string within long strings is "PPL" and "JSS" in string A, respectively. 16 is a distance between the letter "PPL", and 10 is the distance between "JSS". And finally, the goal is to automatically determine repeated words and to express the distance between these words as a list in python.

```
trigrams = [A[i:i+3] for i in range(len(A)-2)]
counts = collections.Counter(trigrams)
repeated = [trigram for trigram, count in counts.items() if count > 1]
```

Through this, I checked which word is repeated. However, I'm wondering how to get the distance of these discriminated words. For example, we don't know how to get the distance between "PPL" and other "PPL".

Comment: What is the role of the "16" and "10" in your example output?

Comment: Show your attempts at solving this

Comment: @thethiny We have a better shot of not putting off new SO contributors if we nicely ask for improvements in the comments.

Comment: @user1717828 Thank you for the comment. I edited my question. 16 is a distance between the letter "PPL", and 10 is the distance between "JSS".

Comment: What is the definition of a word here?

Comment: @NathanXabedi I defined the repetitive part of that long string as "word." I intended the word to be the "PPL" and "JSS" parts.

Comment: @thethiny I edited the content with adding what I tried. Only thing left is to discriminate the distance between the letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4664889/287954):

```
import collections, re
```

Code copied from question:

```
A = "AEJXKWKJSSSJKZJLJLEJSSLKXMPPLSSKKDNEMSMLDMMEPPLETFMM"                                                                                                                                                                            

trigrams = [A[i:i+3] for i in range(len(A)-2)]
counts = collections.Counter(trigrams)
repeated = [trigram for trigram, count in counts.items() if count > 1]
```

Find distances using regex:

```
dists = {}
for r in repeated:
    matches = [m for m in re.finditer(r, A)]
    dists[r] = matches[1].start() - (matches[0].end()-1)                                                                                                                                                                                

print(dists)
```

Output:

```
{'JSS': 10, 'PPL': 16}
```

This of course finds only the distance between the first two matches. You didn't specify if further occurrences should count.

Answer (score 1):

This uses find and string slicing method

```
def find_distance_in_dups(string,length):
  dict_words={}
  for i in range(len(string)-length-1):
    word = string[i:length+i]
    distance=string[string.find(word)+length:].find(word)+1
    #print(distance)
    if distance > 0:
      dict_words[word]=distance
  #print(dict_words)
  return dict_words
print(find_distance_in_dups("AEJXKWKJSSSJKZJLJLEJSSLKXMPPLSSKKDNEMSMLDMMEPPLETFMM",3))
```

Comment: The error occurs this. "NameError: name 'dict_words' is not defined" What did you mean?

Comment: I added the empty initialisation for dict_words. Please try again

Answer (score 0):

Just wrote this one,

To solve your problem you however have to indicate the length of the word you are looking for I think as a parameter.

```
import numpy as np 

def find_duplicates(string,length=3):
    all_words = np.array([string[0+i:length+i] for i in range(len(string)-length)])
    unique_words = np.unique(all_words)
    dico = {}
    for unique in unique_words:
        loc = np.where(all_words==unique)[0]
        if len(loc)>1:
            dico[unique] = np.diff(loc) - (length - 1) #distance between consecutive duplicates
    return dico

A = "AEJXKWKJSSSJKZJLJLEJSSLKXMPPLSSKKDNEMSMLDMMEPPLETFMM"

print(find_duplicates(A,length=3)) # {'JSS': 10, 'PPL': 16}
```

Comment: What's the role of np.where(three_words==unique)[0]? It seems "np.where(three_words==unique)" prints array[x] and dtype. So adding [0] means array[x], but I can't understand what this means.

Comment: Yes, and you want the array[x] from the tuple output of np.where