# How do you find a string in another string in python?

Tags: python, string, for-loop, if-statement, indexing

How do you find a string in another string in python? for example, finding the string "a" in the string "banana" and print how many times it occurs.

Comment: The answer of @mark is the simplest on, alternatively you can use the package "re", to find all occurrences via a regex expression: len(re.findall("a", "banana"))

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4664889/7509907

Basically what you can do is to use regular expressions like this:

```
import re

string = 'banana'
substring = 'a'

# this will give you a list of indexes where the substring occurs in the string
# you can use len() to get the number of occurances
occurance_idxs = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(substring, string)]

print(occurance_idxs)
print(len(occurance_idxs))
```

output

```
[1, 3, 5]
3
```