# Multiple words in single keyword and counting them in the data in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory, keyword-search

I'm trying to run the following code in python in order to count the keywords in the specific values of my dictionary. Suppose my `keywords = ['is', 'my']` and it works fine for me but when my keywords are `keywords = ['is', 'my name']` then it doesn't count the keyword `my name`. I don't know what mistake I'm doing. if anyone can see the code and help me out. thank you

```
from collections import Counter
import json 
from typing import List, Dict


keywords = ['is', 'my name']

def get_keyword_counts(text: str, keywords: List[str]) -> Dict[str, int]:
    return {
        word: count for word, count in Counter(text.split()).items()
        if word in set(keywords)
    }

    data = {
        "policy": {
            "1": {
                "ID": "ML_0",
                "URL": "www.a.com",
                "Text": "my name is Martin and here is my code"
            },
            "2": {
                "ID": "ML_1",
                "URL": "www.b.com",
                "Text": "my name is Mikal and here is my code"
            }
        }
    }
    
    for policy in data['policy'].values():
        policy.update(get_keyword_counts(policy['Text'], keywords))
    print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Comment: text.split() splits at every space.  For example 'foo my word'.split() gives ['foo', 'my', 'word'] not ['foo', 'my word']: so you'll never get 'my word' in your Counter.

Comment: @slothrop What could be the possible solution please? Thank you

Comment: Some ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring.  In your case, you probably care about word boundaries (you want to match "my word" but not "scammy wordles"), and an approach based on regular expressions would work well for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The substring "my name" is also splitted in get_keyword_counts so there is no actual value "my name", they are apart: "my" and "name". I guess you want to count it as a whole, so there is what you need:

```
def get_keyword_counts(text: str, keywords: List[str]) -> Dict[str, int]:
    return {
        word: text.count(word) for word in keywords
    }
```

Comment: Say text="grimy nameplate" and word="my name".  Then text.count(word)=1: is that what is required?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `text.split()`, which eventually splits `"my"` and `"name"` separately, so instead use `count()` and that should do it.