# Use index() to find multiple identical strings in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have a string. The letter `'o'` appears twice in the whole string, but when I try to use the `index()` function to locate the position where the `'o'` appears, it just traverses from left to right and stops when it finds the first `'o'`.

Why can't `index()` print all the locations of `'o'`?

If possible, how can I use `index()` to print all the strings that meet the conditions?

```
a = 'HaloPython!'
print(a.index('o'))
```

Comment: The index() method returns the position at the first occurrence of the specified value.

Comment: read the documentation of the python string index function ... the answer is there

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find all occurrences of a substring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring)

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate of this one [How to find all occurrences of a substring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring). This question is more about whether index() can return all contained strings. So I think this is a separate question. Obviously, index() can only return the first value. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`index` returns exactly one index per call. It's not going to try to shove all indices into the result, changing return type based on the values.

Two obvious ways to handle it:

1. A listcomp with `enumerate`:

   ```
   allindices = [i for i, x in enumerate(a) if x == 'o']
   ```
2. A loop that calls `index` with an explicit `start` argument:

   ```
   idx = -1  # -1 means first search will begin at beginning of string
   try:
       while True:
           idx = a.index('o', idx + 1)  # Resume search after last index found
           print(idx)
   except ValueError:
       pass  # Ran out of 'o's, we're done
   ```

The listcomp solution is by far the most common and obvious solution (and can be made to work for length > 1 substrings by using `start` modified calls to `str.startswith`), but if you *must* use `index` to do it, option #2 exists.