# Print all the "a" of a string on python

Tags: python, string, find

I'm trying to print all the "a" or other characters from an input string. I'm trying it with the .find() function but just print one position of the characters. How do I print all the positions where is an specific character like "a"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find all occurrences of a substring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find` with while loop

```
a = "aabababaa"
k = 0
while True:
    k = a.find("a", k) # This is saying to start from where you left
    if k == -1:
        break
    k += 1
    print(k)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is also possible with much less amount of code if you don't care where you want to start.

```
a = "aabababaa"

for i, c in enumerate(a): # i = Index, c = Character. Using the Enumerate()
  if ("a" in c):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some first-get-all-matches-and-then-print versions:

With a list comprehension:

```
s = "aslkbasaaa"

CHAR = "a"
pos = [i for i, char in enumerate(s) if char == CHAR]
print(*pos, sep='\n')
```

or with [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) and composition of functions

```
from itertools import compress

s = "aslkbasaaa"

CHAR = "a"
pos = compress(range(len(s)), map(CHAR.__eq__, s))
print(*pos, sep='\n')
```