# Python - Using regex to find multiple matches and print them out

Tags: python, regex

I need to find content of forms from HTML source file, I did some searching and found very good method to do that, but the problem is that it prints out only first found, how can I loop through it and output all form contents, not just first one?

```
line = 'bla bla bla<form>Form 1</form> some text...<form>Form 2</form> more text?'
matchObj = re.search('<form>(.*?)</form>', line, re.S)
print matchObj.group(1)
# Output: Form 1
# I need it to output every form content he found, not just first one...
```

Comment: You really don't want to parse HTML with regular expressions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Please refer this  
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873361/finding-multiple-occurrences-of-a-string-within-a-string-in-python][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873361/finding-multiple-occurrences-of-a-string-within-a-string-in-python

Answer (score 109, accepted):

[**Do not use regular expressions to parse HTML.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

But if you ever need to find all regexp matches in a string, use the [`findall`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall) function.

```
import re
line = 'bla bla bla<form>Form 1</form> some text...<form>Form 2</form> more text?'
matches = re.findall('<form>(.*?)</form>', line, re.DOTALL)
print(matches)

# Output: ['Form 1', 'Form 2']
```

Comment: what does the re.S do?

Comment: Makes the `'.'` special character match any character at all, including a newline; without this flag, `'.'` will match anything *except* a newline. ( http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.S )

Comment: Oh, I see, I did go to the webpage but didn't understand the documentation because nothing was underneath re.S but now I see how to read the documentation, re.S and re.DOTALL are the same...thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! `re.DOTALL` is more clear, I've updated the answer.

Comment: This is the best method. Just to confirm, as findall returns a normal array, access results with matches[0], matches[1], etc

Answer (score 44):

Instead of using `re.search` use `re.findall` it will return you all matches in a `List`. Or you could also use `re.finditer` (which i like most to use) it will return an `Iterator Object` and you can just use it to iterate over all found matches.

```
line = 'bla bla bla<form>Form 1</form> some text...<form>Form 2</form> more text?'
for match in re.finditer('<form>(.*?)</form>', line, re.S):
    print match.group(1)
```

Comment: what does the re.S do?

Comment: `re.finditer` is exactly what I needed!Thanks!

Comment: @Pinocchio 
docs say:
re.S is the same as re.DOTALL

``Make the '.' special character match any character at all, including a newline; without this flag, '.' will match anything except a newline.``

(posted this because I believe people like me often come to stackoverflow.com to find answers quickly)

Comment: I'm not sure why this isn't the accepted answer - `finditer` is correct. `re.search()` returns a match object. `re.finditer()` returns an iterable of all the found match objects (wrap in `list()` to just iterate the whole thing). `findall()` returns just a list of tuples. Naming `finditer` like `findall` was a poor choice - it matches more with `search` and should have been called `searchiter`.

Comment: Yep, agree with matt. This is the best answer. The `finditer()` [match objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) are more powerful than the list `findall()` returns because it lets you handle each match group explicitly and get other metadata about the match(es).

Answer (score 6):

Using regexes for this purpose is the wrong approach. Since you are using python you have a really awesome library available to extract parts from HTML documents: [BeautifulSoup](http://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/&rct=j&q=beautifulsoup&ei=RCOUTvXVOeff4QS3htCqCA&usg=AFQjCNHAxwplurFOBqg5cehWQEVKi-TuLQ&cad=rja).

Comment: Oh I didn't knew, I just discovered Python yesterday. :)