# Match a line with multiple regex using Python

Tags: python, regex

Is there a way to see if a line contains words that matches a set of regex pattern?
If I have `[regex1, regex2, regex3]`, and I want to see if a line matches any of those, how would I do this?
Right now, I am using `re.findall(regex1, line)`, but it only matches 1 regex at a time.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7726095/1599699

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can use the built in functions `any` (or `all` if all regexes have to match) and a Generator expression to cycle through all the regex objects.

`any (regex.match(line) for regex in [regex1, regex2, regex3])`

(or `any(re.match(regex_str, line) for regex in [regex_str1, regex_str2, regex_str2])` if the regexes are not pre-compiled regex objects, of course)

However, that will be inefficient compared to combining your regexes in a single expression. If this code is time- or CPU-critical, you should try instead to compose a single regular expression that encompasses all your needs, using the special `|` regex operator to separate the original expressions.

A simple way to combine all the regexes is to use the string `join` method:

`re.match("|".join([regex_str1, regex_str2, regex_str2]), line)`

A warning about combining the regexes in this way: It can result in wrong expressions if the original ones already do make use of the `|` operator.

Comment: You can make the join method less likely to fail if you wrap each expression in parenthesis.  `'(' + ')|('.join(['foo', 'bar', 'baz']) + ')'` gives `'(foo)|(bar)|(baz)'`.

Comment: Better yet, wrap in `(?:...)`, and put the string together in a way that highlights its logical structure. `'|'.join('(?:{0})'.format(x) for x in ('foo', 'bar', 'baz'))` for example.

Answer (score 10):

Try this new regex: (regex1)|(regex2)|(regex3).  This will match a line with any of the 3 regexs in it.

Comment: `(?:...)` is probably a better idea than `(...)` here, to avoid creating spurious capture groups.

Comment: @Karl ...unless you want to check the truthiness of `.group(n)` to determine *which* group you captured.

Comment: @Karl Can you elaborate your comment? what you means by spurious groups?

Comment: like, groups that are unwanted, not helpful for solving the problem. I think I may have used the word incorrectly. But also that was over 7 years ago.

Answer (score 8):

You cou loop through the regex items and do a search.

```
regexList = [regex1, regex2, regex3]

line = 'line of data'
gotMatch = False
for regex in regexList:
    s = re.search(regex,line)
    if s:
         gotMatch = True
         break

if gotMatch:
    doSomething()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#quite new to python but had the same problem. made this to find all with multiple 
#regular #expressions.

    regex1 = r"your regex here"
    regex2 = r"your regex here"     
    regex3 = r"your regex here"
    regexList = [regex1, regex1, regex3]

    for x in regexList:
    if re.findall(x, your string):
        some_list = re.findall(x, your string)     
        for y in some_list:
            found_regex_list.append(y)#make a list to add them to.
```

Comment: you should include an explanation with your code snippet