# Python regex to match "on" join clause in SQL

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to analyze some SQL using python. I've got SQL that might contain multiple "on" clauses specifying table joins.

e.g

"on tableA.user_id = tableB.id"

I'd like to parse out all of the join relationships.

I tried the following but am having difficulty detecting multiple ones. It just finds the first one and stops there. Can someone help?

```
pattern = re.compile(r'on\s([^"\s]*)\s*=\s*([^"\s]*)')
results = re.search(pattern, sql)
for result in results.groups():
     print result
```

Comment: https://github.com/andialbrecht/sqlparse/ might be useful for you

Comment: Okay, figured it out. I need to use findall:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724993/python-using-regex-to-find-multiple-matches-and-print-them-out

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to python, look into the (very good) python regex docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). It specifically says that re.search only matched one occurrance.

You probably want to use re.match, which will return none if it did not match, and a match object containing all occurrances otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [re.findall()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) function.

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result unless they touch the beginning of another match.