# Python 2.7 input word to search in a txt file output line number and at what character

Tags: python, python-2.7, find

You are given a multi line text file and are asked to input a word that you want to find and the output should tell the user what line the word is located and at what character the word is at ie. (abcd c is the second character starting from zero).

```
f='Abbott: You throw the ball to first base.\nCostello: Then who gets it?\nAbbott: Naturally.\nCostello: Naturally.'
pat=raw_input('Enter a Pattern')
    lines=f.split("\n")
    for i,line in enumerate(lines):
        if pat in line:
            print('{} found on line number {} at character {}'.format(pat, i+1,f.find(pat)))
```

I can't figure out how to do the print statement multiple times if the word is repeated also I cant seem to get the correct character

Comment: This smells of homework for some reason.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873361/finding-multiple-occurrences-of-a-string-within-a-string-in-python this is what you are looking for probably to find a pattern in a string multiple times.